# Increase the minimum character limit for posts

Tags: feature-request, low-quality-posts, question-quality, answer-quality

At the moment, there is a 30 character minimum enforced when posting a question or an answer.

I think that any half decent question or answer would have at least a minimum of 200 characters (a link alone could take up 70–80+ characters). Any less and the post isn't descriptive enough, in my opinion.

I also think that any post with less than 300–400 characters should be added to one of the review queues (late answers/first post or low quality).

Comment: I was under the impression that links don't count when calculating the post's length...

Comment: Current score of +7 doesn't really convey that there has been 18 people for and 11 against. The main reasons to be against of this would be, I think, that 1) there are some legitimate use cases where we would see bananas or something then, 2) it can be easily circumvented, 3) the short posts are already added to low quality review queue and 4) enforced limit would not help anything. You could add to this question your responses on those comments. Especially if we have any proof that enforcing would actually help.

Comment: Tongue in cheek: David Fullerton is looking for quality indicators in posts to know which one to favor when pushing content to the Interesting page.  Let's not make his job harder :)

Comment: @HansPassant who is he?

Comment: The Vice President of Engineering at StackExchange.

Comment: Succinctness is really underrated on StackExchange sometimes...

Comment: If any new limits were added (and I don't think they should be), I would vote for a *maximum* length, to thwart the code dumps.

Comment: @PaulDraper we could limit the number of line breaks. That would allow long explanatory paragraphs, but penalize short code lines.

Answer (score 42):

Here's a legitimate 39-char question:

> Is declaring `void main()` legal in C?

Here's a legitimate 65-char answer:

> No. The C99 standard, §XX.YY requires `main` to return an `int`.

(Note that linking to the C standard PDF is not allowed by ISO.)

I don't think this char limit adds much. It forbids short FAQ-style questions like the above. Besides, it's too easy to beat this limit by just posting a wall of code.

Comment: There would be some valid question so then put all posts less than X characters into one of the review queues.

Comment: I agree. The biggest problem nowadays are the low quality questions. Low quality answers will get downvoted to the bottom of the pile.

Comment: @Howlin That is already done. A post's length is a *huge* factor in calculating a post's quality score which, if below a certain amount, raises an automatic low quality score flag and sends it to the Low Quality Posts review queue.

Comment: Another case: in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13384549/365237) I had a 20-character answer with a code snippet that I struggled with to find anything extra to say to satisfy the character limit. In the end I added "just use range", and now it contains 35 characters plus a link. What should I have added if the answer limit would have been 200 characters?

Comment: Let's just say that the legitimate question is OK (but it should clearly be closed as a duplicate); but the answer is incomplete and inaccurate.  The standard is not the only specification for C.  See: [What should `main()` return in C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c/18721336#18721336).  With the more recent Microsoft compilers, `void main()` is (sadly) legitimate.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: by `s/C/C99/` in the question, it becomes 41 chars long and the answer is complete again (except maybe for a quote).

Comment: The relevant part of the relevant quote becomes _or in some other implementation-defined manner_ (and clearly is intended to allow other return types because of the separate statement _If the return type is not compatible with `int`, the termination status returned to the host environment is unspecified._)

Comment: @animuson, cool that would probably work a bit better. A small request for it that, could posts like [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/195174#resultSets) (low character posts linking to other questions on SO) be added to it as well? It seems that there are quiet a few of them getting through each week (and some are getting accepted as answers).

Answer (score 21):

## So?

Comment: If you force people to post at least 200 characters, they will work around the limit using tricks like above. Answers to some questions can be really short and require no more than 30-80 characters — increasing the minimum character limit for the answer will make people add irrelevant bits just to work around the limit. In my opinion, the current limit works just fine.

Comment: Impressive. I will use it!

Answer (score 5):

Let us throw a few statistics at this. I ran a quick query (the query runs quick, doing it made me non-sql speaker search SO for answers quite a while. But I did not have to post a question):

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/198374/256866/small-questions

Adjust the score and length to your liking (currently score 5, length 50), but what we can clearly see is that there are lots of questions and even much more answers that are rather short. Increasing the limit towards the proposed 200 shows really lots and lots and lots of good questions and answers. Although there are quite some that are not the best, they are after all useful (otherwise they would not have gathered that much votes).

The proposed limit is far too high, and already the present
30 one is sometimes filled up with fill characters to reach the limit since a simple "no, you can not" is sometimes just the answer.

Answer (score 4):

## Yes.

An excellent idea.