# Add terms like 'i am new to', 'i am a beginner' and variants thereof to the low-quality filter and display a warning

Tags: discussion, feature-request, quality-filter

I have noticed that many low-quality questions begin with the asker explicity emphasizing that they have just started programming or learning a new technology. Or put another way, a very large percentage of questions that begin with these words are total crap.

It might help if the system could react to these keywords, and related misspellings, and make it clear that

- being a beginner is not an excuse for not reading the FAQ and how to ask guidelines
- nobody really cares or should care, that the rules will not be relaxed on that account
- beginners can write perfectly good questions if they want to
- putting such terms in their question just increases noise

It also might help if some kind of bubble popped up and provided an in-your-face link to the [better version of the how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), while providing strongs visual hints that not paying attention will have consequences.

Comment: Also, the question should never be about the asker, it's about the question, so if they're a beginner or not is of zero importance. =)

Comment: Add "please don´t downvote me" etc., or the word downvote in general (outside of meta)

Comment: Just block questions that contain `i` or more than one uncapitalized sentence.

Comment: And questions with all caps

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I like to use `i` as a loop control variable, you insensitive clod!

Comment: FWIW, sometimes people are scared of the backlash at 'easy questions' and feel the need to apologize/excuse their ignorance.  If everyone were kind to beginners, it would be less of an issue.

Comment: And any question that starts "i wanna"

Comment: @thumbtackthief If everyone were to do a bit of research effort before asking a question, (people would be more kind and) it would be less of an issue.

Comment: Advanced users forget the degree of difficulty of 'a bit of research effort' for a new user.  Either way, there's no excuse for being rude.

Comment: @thumbtackthief, most likely the people putting these qualifiers in their questions haven't been around the site long enough to build up a proper fear of anything, other than just a general fear of looking stupid.

Comment: @thumbtackthief There's also no excuse for doing **absolutely no** research effort, which appears to be the case with a massive amount of questions. I, for one, try to avoid being rude, but its really hard when I read some of these questions.

Comment: Also block questions that have the PHP tag (just kidding).

Comment: That's fine--by all means say so (ideally constructively--helping someone learn how to help themselves with some guidance in reading docs can be an amazing help).  I'm not saying let lazy askers off the hook.  I'm just saying I understand why people write "I'm a beginner".  There are definitely posters that will eat beginners alive regardless of whether or not effort was shown in the question.

Comment: The ability to do your own research and self teaching isn't really related to your level of proficiency.  It's a separate skill, and one that is absolutely essential to be a productive participant in this site.

Comment: "Plz go easy on me im new. so I was lerngin php how to add to strngis pls" - "This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a question a professional or enthusiast programmer would ask."

Comment: @bjb568 That's not an off-topic reason.

Comment: @Wooble - it's people like you who make my code reviews such a headache, you insensitive clod

Comment: @thumbtackthief - "If everyone was kind to the experts who answered questions and followed some BASIC and EASY rules, there would be no need to be rude". Fixed that for you.

Comment: @Jason IMO research and self teaching is _another_ skill that one has to learn. So when someone begins with `'I am a noob'`, he may even mean `'I don't know how or where should I look this up.'` For example I didn't understand a damn word on http://en.cppreference.com until some 1-1,5 years into my C++ studies.

Comment: If one's concern as an asker is that questions from beginners are attacked _ipso facto_, wouldn't one do everything in one's power to **hide** the fact that one is a beginner, @thumbtackthief, rather than open with that declaration?

Comment: @jadarnel Other?

Comment: When you say "_some kind of bubble popped up and provided an in-your-face link to the better version of the how-to-ask page_", how about something like [this feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260039/57475)

Comment: Can we add "thanks" to the list? It also always correlates with someone treating SO as a forum and not a Q&A site.

Comment: @jadarnel27 I think he was referring to this post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/257979/57475

Comment: SO is supposed to be just a Q & A forum to offer or get help in a voluntary basis for the former. It's not a field of war. That is why probably the so called "beginners" ask help by stating "I am a beginner". They try to avoid the shots...To use Anaxagoras words [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaxagoras) "Don't humiliate the one you consider inferior"

Comment: @bjb568 I'm saying "*...because it is not a question a professional or enthusiast programmer would ask.*" is not an appropriate reason to close a question.  So using the "other" option to do that is not the right way to go.

Comment: I consider myself a beginner in respect of jQuery and PHP. But, I always try putting in effort into asking coherent questions along with Titles - it helps me clarify what I mean, and sometimes it makes me realise where I'm going wrong with a Script. But! I wonder if my questions are not as succinct as they could be... I feel that I should take the time to explain clearly and thoroughly, as opposed to "Can some do this for me, this is what I don't understand, any ideas", which doesn't help ME. A coherent question helps ME. The trick seems to be knowing when to ask. We learn by asking and doing.

Comment: Saying you're a beginner also means you need a low level answer

Comment: Sometimes a beginner wants to ask a good question, but the lack of knowledge on the subject makes it difficult to provide the correct information / ask the question properly. They should be making an honest effort to ask a decent question though.

Comment: my favorite is "is this even possible?" as in "I want to display just the month/year of a Date.  **Is this even possible ?**".   The answer is of course, "yes".  but the comments requires more chars than that, and those answers, though 100% accurate and complete, end up in the LQP queue

Comment: DThomas, exactly... more than once I've opened up a new question window only to answer it myself as I try and figure out how to formulate it appropriately.  @marczellm, absolutely research and self teaching must also be learned, but this is not the place to learn it, it's enough to just focus on the programming.

Comment: Instead of adding them to the low quality queue, why not just prevent them from being posted with a notice as to why they can't post questions like that?

Comment: I would consider a "Beginners Quarter", since some beginners do actually help each other. All Beginners and Experts present in one space/place will always lead to a sort of deluded learning space, similar to mix-ability classes.  

To clarify: "Knowing when to ask" means that a beginner should try answering their own questions through testing and research. All questions have already been answered! Personally, I post on StackOverflow as a last resort http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260205/add-terms-like-i-am-new-to-i-am-a-beginner-and-variants-thereof-to-the-low?cb=1#comment41186_260205

Comment: diluted, not deluded ^, but then again ...

Comment: I love the idea of "help at point of use." I'd also like to see it on the Xcode tag when the text of the question doesn't contain the word "Xcode". I've found that's usually a good indicator that Xcode is in no way involved in the question or answer.

Comment: As for the research effort needed for a beginner being higher than a more advanced user that's right. Not everybody is able to explain himself like an Oxford graduate thus writing a page or two worth of quality content, that may also classify as an official academic document of learning. When these users get overwhelmed by all those trigger warnings they feel claustrophobic and frustrated at the same time, even before interacting with the post-backslash that make them feel even more bad.

Comment: @user1118321, there was a user `H2CO3` who's worked is to clean the question tagged with "XCode".

Comment: Close the question instantly.  They have just admitted they are not a professional or enthusiast programmer :)

Comment: @Plutonix: a comment stating "Yes, it most certainly is." works fine.

Comment: @DNA I strongly dislike the word "wanna", but often it's used by non-native speakers, even when they're trying to write English well. I often see it on lang-8.com entries, for example. I think adding it to a filter would be a bad idea.

Comment: @RobertHarvey that would also block people that cannot put code tags correctly considering that `i` is quite commonly used in code. Would it be considered a bonus side-effect then?

Comment: What happened to the "be nice" thing that SO once tried to advocate? Is that a joke in light of all these "onto your face" visual aid about consequences etc.? Now questioners can't even mention their background? What's the fuss here all about?

Answer (score 70):

Providing helpful hints in response to trigger words or phrases seems proportionate and useful (and I would dearly love an automated response to any question beginning with "i wanna" and similar abominations - but that's probably better used as a quality metric to flag for review).

*Update: "help at the point of use" is a valuable UI concept - give someone a FAQ and they often won't read it. Pop up the relevant section at a relevant time, and it's much more digestible (provided you get the relevance right!)*

However, there is at least one benefit of stating "I am a beginner", particularly for difficult topics, in that it enables the answerer to tune the level of their explanation so that the OP has some chance of 'getting it'.

I have a reasonable rep, but if I were asking a question on [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell), for example, then I would be tempted to mention that I am a n00b, because I am concerned that I'll get an answer along the lines of the [infamous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870088/a-monad-is-just-a-monoid-in-the-category-of-endofunctors-whats-the-problem):

> A monad is just a monoid in the category of endofunctors, what's the problem?

...or maybe [something](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Zygohistomorphic_prepromorphisms) about [Zygohistomorphic prepromorphisms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057136/real-world-applications-of-zygohistomorphic-prepromorphisms), along with a link to a research paper on cutting-edge abstract algebra.

Perhaps the rep of the OP should also be taken into account when deciding whether to auto-nag them?

Comment: `"There is at least one benefit of stating 'I am a beginner'"` - except that, for the most part, it's just noise, and we edit it out for that reason, not to mention that the exact classification of "beginner" varies between people. The question you ask, the way you ask it, and the research you've done should indicate your proficiency. Not to mention that we should try to accommodate most levels of understanding with our answers - **it shouldn't matter if OP is a beginner** - someone who reads the answer in future might be - ideally they should also understand.

Comment: Ideally, it shouldn't matter. But in reality it often does - some topics involve abstractions that take months or years to absorb. An answer that a beginner can understand cannot use any of these abstractions. Nor can it explain them, since many of them have entire book chapters devoted to them. So the answerer is faced with a choice: answer concisely and correctly using advanced concepts - or answer (perhaps less fully) by analogy, code recipe, or by reference to more detailed material, etc.

Comment: There is often some ambiguity between "I have never written any kind of program before and I am trying to use technology X" versus "I have some experience as a programmer but this is the first time I've touched technology X" - I've certainly seen both situations with the text "I am new in X". There often has to be one question first to establish the asker's overall experience level.

Comment: @DNA Welcome to the new SO where it seems Idealism > Practicality

Comment: If you're getting answers that are over your head, you should use comments and edits to clarify what you do and don't understand. "I'm a noob" is void for vagueness -- what, specifically, is the relevant knowledge you already have?

Comment: @SList - they most certainly are words in the English language.  But if you have a particular dislike for those words (or others) then please feel free to edit the question.  Be careful there, you're starting to sound like a snob.  Lighten up dude :)

Comment: "Perhaps the rep of the OP should also be taken into account when deciding whether to auto-nag them?" — surely "I wanna do X, plz help me" is *worse* from a high rep user though? :)

Comment: @anotherdave Good point, we clearly need a more complex heuristic that penalises those who should know better, whilst being gently helpful to genuine beginners ;-)

Comment: @DNA My experience is that in most cases you can easily determine the level of expertise of the OP from reading the question, and adjust the technical level of your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 33):

I put together a Data Explorer query that [ranks the quality of recent questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/200733/stats-for-questions-like?Phrase=I+am+a+beginner&Weeks=6) that have 'catch' phrases in them. (remember, closed questions get deleted, and are not in SEDE after a while, which skews these results badly). The following two are in the subject line:

- [I am a beginner](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/200733/stats-for-questions-like?Phrase=I+am+a+beginner&Weeks=6)

> ```
> Phrase          Matching Closed DownVoted DownvoteTotal DownvotedScore NoVotes UpVoted UpvoteTotal UpvotedScore 
>
> --------------- -------- ------ --------- ------------- -------------- ------- ------- ----------- ------------ 
>
> I am a beginner 375      76     126       -241          -1.912698      186     107     62          0.579439
> ```

- [I am new to](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/200733/stats-for-questions-like?Phrase=I+am+new+to&Weeks=6)

> ```
> Phrase      Matching Closed DownVoted DownvoteTotal DownvotedScore NoVotes UpVoted UpvoteTotal UpvotedScore 
>
> ----------- -------- ------ --------- ------------- -------------- ------- ------- ----------- ------------ 
>
> I am new to 3192     339    747       -1162         -1.555555      1940    741     602         0.812415
> ```

What does this all mean?

- It means that people have learned not to use "beginner" and instead, 10-times as many say "I am new to"
- About 1 in 5 "beginner" questions get closed
- About 1 in 10 "new to" questions get closed
- about half of all questions never get any votes
- about a quarter get upvoted
- about a quarter get downvoted
- when people downvote, they hit it hard... and there's normally more-than-one.
- when people upvote, there's also normally a downvote in there too.

Now, what does *that* mean, well, it probably means people don't vote enough, and people don't edit enough.

In the context of this meta question, it means about 1-in-5 questions with these 'triggers' could possibly benefit from a popup.

How does this compare to other questions? Well, what about questions asked by users with > 2K rep?

- [Questions by Users with more than 2K Rep](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/200734/stats-for-questions-from-repusers?Reputation=2000&Weeks=6)

> ```
> MinRep Matching Closed DownVoted DownvoteTotal DownvotedScore NoVotes UpVoted UpvoteTotal UpvotedScore 
>
> ------ -------- ------ --------- ------------- -------------- ------- ------- ----------- ------------ 
>
> 2000   16186    736    1702      2543          1.494124       8788    6782    15954       2.352403
> ```

Here we see that:

- 1 in 20 get closed (compare 1 in 10)
- 1 in 10 get downvoted (compare 1 in 4)
- 1 in 2 get no votes at all (compare 1 in 2 - interesting!)
- 1 in 2 get upvoted (compare 1 in 4)
- when questions are upvoted, they get 3 times the votes as beginners....

Comment: there seems to be a correlation between the reputation and the community response

Comment: A question by a n00b you don't understand **must** be bad; downvote. A question by a l33t you don't understand **must** be good; upvote.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier It's not because of the reputation of the asker we upvote a post. It's because of the quality of the question.

Comment: My pet theory is that it is a simple case of numbers... many of the people who ask bad questions the first-time-round get so pissed at SE for closing/downvoting them, that they never come back. It is natural then that the quality of questions by people who post more than one question is increased... because most crappy posters only post once.

Comment: "About 1 in 5 "beginner" questions get closed"  In other words, 80% of beginner questions are not closed, or 90% if you use the 1 in 10 figure.  Clearly, some beginner questions are low-quality (what do you expect?), but that is by no means the rule.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen - I made mention of the fact that many (most) closed questions are automatically deleted after 5 days or so. Deleted questions are not populated in the Data Explorer, so what you see as closed questions is really only the closed-questions-in-the-last-of-the-six-week dataset. There are probably 6X as many closed questions (for `beginner`, `new-to`, and `experienced` askers)

Answer (score 23):

These are some low-quality questions that contain the phrase "I am a beginner" or the like:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161303/dynamically-update-content-as-the-site-gets-updated **[-7/Closed]**
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429434/i-am-a-beginner-studiyng-help-plz **[-9/Closed]**
- [I am a beginner in C, could anybody please help me with the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821174/i-am-a-beginner-in-c-could-anybody-please-help-me-with-the-output) **[-6/Closed]**

Now, these are some questions that people apparently found useful and upvoted:

- [Is it good practice to put try-catch in a loop until all statements in the try block is executed without any exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108891/is-it-a-good-practice-to-put-try-catch-in-a-loop-until-all-statements-in-the-try) **[+8, Open]**
- [Pythonic way of replacing real return values and implementation of functions with mock ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075851/pythonic-way-of-replacing-real-return-values-and-implementation-of-functions-wit) **[+5, Open]**
- [Echo issue with while / if / else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23332264/echo-issue-with-while-if-else) **[+5, Open]**

My point? You can't reliably determine the quality of a question just by searching for phrases like "*i'm newbie*", "*i'm beginner*" etc.

I don't think adding a separate notification pop-up for these kind of questions is worth it. It's not like people are going to read it anyway. They will just continue doing the same thing over and over again, until it reaches a point where they *can't* ask any more questions.

If you encounter a question that is otherwise good and salvagable, **edit it** to remove the noise. Those who want to learn will get it from the edit. If you're feeling extra helpful, you can go ahead and (try to) educate the OP in the comments section under the question.

Comment: SE has also branched out into more sites. There's well, [these](http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-traffic).

Comment: My personal favorite: Stack Exchange Gardening and Landscaping

Comment: Either way the phrases are just noise, lets all agree with that ;)

Comment: [rolfl's answer below](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260283/1933347) has great numbers to look at, rather than selective sampling. You may want to take a look!

Comment: I just edited the "I am a beginner/noob" noise out of those upvoted examples you give. Because it is just noise. Apologies for sabotaging your examples!!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: No worries. Here's [more of them](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22am+a+beginner%22+score%3A..5), if you're interested. Edit away!

Comment: Pointing at some good questions that contains the phrase proves only that sometimes the question is good. But so what, if the vast majority of questions with the phrase are bad?

Comment: @Raedwald: Yes. As evidenced by the data shown in [rolfl's answer below](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260283/1438393), about 1 in 5 of "i'm beginner" questions get closed. With all such phrases combined together, the ratio will be even higher. Most of the times, these questions will be of low-quality.

Comment: @Braiam I would agree that calling them *noise* is a bit rude to the user reading these comments, isn't it?

Comment: @abdellahmansur: Not really, because they *are* noise. Posts on Stack Exchange sites do not need "Hi/hello" addressing or "Thanks in advance" etc. in it. Stack Overflow is not a forum.

Comment: @AmalMurali I know it's not a forum and we don't begin,end questions/answers with "hi"/"hello".. but there's no need to be rude either addressing users mistakes as *noise*. You'd be surprised how many users change their attitude/habits of writing if you don't address their "things" in a rude way.

Comment: @abdellahmansur: Personally, I don't feel calling things that are noise, noise is insulting. Also, you're not directly addressing the user saying "HEY YOU. YER STUFF NOISE." or something, so I don't see why it is a problem.

Comment: @AmalMurali  It's not a problem.  Noise isn't insulting; it's a technical term, 100% correct in this context.

Comment: @Poldie: Yes, indeed; that's the point I was trying to make. abdellah mansur was the one saying it is insulting, not me.

Answer (score 12):

I certainly hope that the quality filter is built using some sort of machine learning approach and not via a list of words and phrases. If that's true, then this question is moot. If you train a classifier on a sufficient body of crap questions, it will learn the clues for itself.

Answer (score 0):

**My story and thinking of a problem**

---

I joined Stack Overflow two years back, and when I looked back at my old questions and answers, I read many mistakes I made, and I corrected them. I believe that when someone starts asking a question here (even for the first time), he/she may make mistakes, but which should not bother <strike>others</strike> *if the problem is real and clear*.

**Sometime I couldn't understand the reality of a question**

---

I've seen many questions for iOS (Objective-C), which needs really good experience to work, still they had written, "I am new to iOS...High Resolution Question...Any idea/suggestion?"

I was wonder how a person who is new to the technology and still he's asking such a question which isn't acceptable work for a fresher. Anyway, still I'm not against this, as I thought he may be concerned with that topic and not for the iOS.

**Needs improvements everywhere**

---

What the site needs to improve **for the users** is to teach them how to make crystal clear representation of questions/answers,

- How to ask - make it like a new user or even an existing user would love to read.
- Let, tell them with real examples of how to ask, what to ask, and what to not ask.
- Show them the value of reputation points which they will earn here.

Need of an **improved / rich way of** asking a question or giving an answer,

- Autocorrection - while typing a question or giving an answer, look for <strike>grammer</strike> grammar and spellings mistakes. Allow the user to correct them by hover over it.
- Give more features when asking a question - highlight tools, colour/font/font size selection.
- Table drawing to show data tabulated form (see @rolfl answer).
- Force the user to correct any grammar / spell mistakes before posting a question / an answer.

Make "**cron jobs**" for the site, which runs periodically, would select questions/answers which marked with "Need corrections flag" - *introduced just now!*. Will learn the pattern there, and next time will use that wrong pattern for newly questions or answers to check for grammar/spells/pattern of asking. I am not sure how tough / easy it is this to implement, but nothing is impossible to implement. Today or tomorrow we'll need it.

Comment: "Give more features when asking a question - highlight tools, colour/font/font size selection". That's a joke, right? Must *everyone's* question jump out of the crowd? There are more than enough 24 pt bold questions as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

I am noticing a recent(?) trend of putting ‘I am a beginner’ in the question title. Just a couple examples:

- [I am a beginer at programming,I wrote a code which gives perfect output but online judge didn't accepted.Why it's happen?(Codeforces problem 69A. )](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67737786/3840170)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/68376228/3840170 (deleted; title was ‘C++ problem about this net thing :( i'm just biginner’)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/68518906/3840170 (deleted; title was ‘I need help solving this problem I think it's easy but I'm a beginner’)
- [I am a beginner at C and am encountering some error in the functioning of the while loop kindly, if possible guide me how to handle this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68548233/3840170)

While some here have pointed possible benefits of mentioning that in the question body, putting it in the title just adds noise.  I think those phrases should be blocked from titles just like ‘plz halp meh’, ‘i have problem’ and similar phrases.  Maybe direct askers to mention this **at the bottom** of the question body, if at all.

Comment: IIRC the title filters only kick in with less than 40 characters, so none of those would have failed it anyway.