# Should phrases such as 'I am new to X' be edited out of questions?

Tags: support, edits

When I make an edit to a question, should I also be editing out 'fluff' statements from the question? Is this justification for an edit to a question, even if no other changes are made?

For example, [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260205/add-terms-like-i-am-new-to-i-am-a-beginner-and-variants-thereof-to-the-low) identifies that many questions begin with the statement "I am new to X". Just because someone new to a technology, they may ask an important question, and these statements don't provide any extra information. In fact, this might give an answerer the wrong impression that the question is trivial (when, it may not be). So, it seems as though editing them out might be beneficial. What's the policy here?

Comment: Ask yourself: will a *future visitor* with the same technical problem *care* if the original question asker was new to the language?

Comment: I love it when people ask really basic and/or goofy questions and they feel the need to tell us they're noobs.  Well, son, no skeet.

Comment: _no skeet_ - I don't think that word means what you think it means.

Comment: @BSMP does it mean what I think you think Will does not think it means? If not, what *exactly* does it mean?

Comment: @royhowie - Probably.

Comment: Key phrases like these are useful: I know where to target my down/close votes.  The OP's example, and 'I searched on the net but didn't find anything', are pretty accurate signals that the question is going to be VLQ.  As such ,they are actually 'useful noise' that should be left in until the question is deleted or, (most unlikey); answered to form a good SO contribution.

Comment: Short answer: yes. There is no long answer.

Comment: @MartinJames I edit the ones I feel are (potentially) a diamond in the rough.

Comment: I guess the implicit assumption here is that the question being edited is worth editing - ie. it shouldn't just be downvoted/flagged/closed. I'm not planning on going through and editing out these statements out of every post on SO - I'd be here for the rest of my life :).

Comment: I wouldn't approve an edit if that were the only change made.   But if making other edits, I would remove that as well.   That said, has anyone else noticed that "I am new to X" pretty much always means "I am too lazy to research this myself".

Comment: If anyone is wondering *why* people add those phrases it's sometimes so as not to get down voted by those who think it is an obvious question without much thought put into it. I've done it myself a couple of times.

Comment: @camden_kid - down-voting should be on the merits of the content of the question though, not whether the user is inexperienced or an expert. I agree with Martin James' comment: questions with these phrases are more likely larger targets for downvoting and/or other negative reviewing (perhaps rightly so in many cases).

Comment: It is my impression people use the "I am new to....." bit as a preemptive strike against trigger happy downvoters...The attitude of many in this community has lead people to be sort of afraid of asking (silly) questions therefor trying to justify any pitfalls by starting the questions in that manner. Whether it should be edited or not, I think it should.

Comment: @camden_kid, OK, but it does not work.  Such phrases attract closevotes like free pizza attracts developers.

Comment: The best way *to* include extra information like that is probably a comment on your own post.  Not related to removing, but a better alternative for avoiding the problem in the first place.

Comment: I am new to juggling firesticks. So pls dont downvote my comment.  A good response is "yes, but you are not new to asking questions"

Comment: When fellow user asks with statements like _"Im new with... "_, or _"I came from this language, then I'm starting to learn..."_, they [implicitly, or subconsciously] want the people (who _genuinely_ wants to answer) to provide them the answer in a manner a newbie can grasp. When answering questions from _"newbie"_, I tend to overly detailed then bombard it with a lot of comments- because I know that will help them since they are, indeed, newbie. Its not lacking of professionalism, maybe just think of it as **setting up the mood for a tutorial-conversation**.

Comment: @Gideon Why don't you do that for *every single post*?  You should be writing every answer in a way that is there to teach, and convey information to someone who doesn't understand the concepts they're asking about.

Comment: @Servy Of course you'll not do that to every of your single post. I _think_ you must do that only when you want to be answered on an _"newbie"_ level (e.g. every details, with comments, very verbose, etc). If you are not to expect that same level of _newby_ness, then don't specify that you're newbie-- It defeats the purpose of saying: _"you're new to ..."

Comment: @Servy And everyone is expected to answer every post they can in a manner _both_ newbies and old-timers can fully comprehend-- even if the user who asked **doesn't** explicitly specified his level of experience on the field... Only the problem is sometimes, we (yep, _including_ me), do not.

Comment: @Servy: Some experts dislike such a manner of "dumbing-down" their answers, citing Stack Overflow's tagline being a site for "professional and enthusiast programmers". Also, not every topic can be distilled to something accessible even to newbies without running the risk of over-simplification (and, subsequently, downvotes, when said over-simplification results in inaccurate information).

Comment: @BSMP: Maybe not if someone else were saying it, but I'm pretty sure it *does* mean what *Will* thinks it means.

Comment: @BoltClock If a particular question is something that new programmers are simply never going to face, you don't need to consider them a part of the target audience of that question.  This is where it comes down to explaining the concepts that are core to the question itself, but not explaining background information that's not core to the question being asked, and that is simply information that one would need to already know to be in the position of asking the question.

Comment: For the ones wondering, like me, VLQ stands for very low quality.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Such content is noise; feel free to remove it when editing such posts.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80152/discussion-on-answer-by-servy-should-phrases-such-as-i-am-new-to-x-be-edited-o). Like in posts, we want to keep comments *uncluttered*, we have chat for the human connection. (see what I did there?)

Comment: **Moderator notice**: I cleared another umpteen comments; if you agree or disagree, you vote. If you want to add to the discussion, post an answer. If you want to argue back and forth, use chat.

Answer (score 74):

I believe there is one case when it probably should stay.  When it's accompanied by `"but I know Y very well"`.  Then we might be able to use `Y` terminology to explain `X`.

Comment: Yes - an algorithm or design outline in pseudocode can help with language-agnostic questions.

Comment: It also happens quite often that terminology changes from one language/platform to another, or sometimes even the same words mean something different in the other context. It can be useful to know where the OP comes from in those cases indeed (and the resulting answers can generally be useful to others too anyway).

Answer (score 67):

I'm going to throw in a small, dissenting vote . . . sometimes, it helps me to know the level of experience of someone when writing an answer.  For example. if someone states that they aren't familiar with regular expressions, I'm much more likely to explain the parts of a pattern that I put in my answer, than if they know regex and are just having trouble coming up with a solution for a tricky match.

Sometimes you can effectively cater your response based on context clues, but, it's much easier when the person tells you straight up that they don't know anything yet.

And, for that matter, I think there is actually some value in having "beginner" (more explanation) and "expert" (less explanation, based on assumed existing knowledge) versions of answers for people looking for help on this site.

---

**TL;DR** - "Hello", "Thanks", "My name is _____", etc. are all noise, but providing an experience level can actually help with creating better answers.

Comment: You should explain your answer anyway if you want to give the best answer possible. Answers aren't just for the OP- They're also for future visitors. Those future visitors may have more or less experience than the OP, but you have no way to know. If you want to create a better answer, _explain your answer_ regardless of how experienced you think the OP is. Chances are, if the person is searching for the answer, they don't understand why their code isn't working anyway.

Comment: I agree with: *... but providing an expereince level can actually help with creating better answers*

Comment: @Kendra - I actually don't completely agree with that . . . I've been coding for over 20 years, but that doesn't mean that there aren't times when I get stumped while trying to solve a problem.  I don't need my toolsets explained to me, I just need some advice on new ways to apply them.  The answers here are written to help the asker, with hopes that other people wil also benefit from the discussion.  The instructions on accepting answers even say "Accepting doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked."

Comment: @hek2mgl: These are the main problems: 1. The first few lines are shown as an excerpt. Congratulations on blowing that on pure fluff. 2. The answer should be for all readers, not the OP alone, we are not a support-line. 3. The level will be set by the whole question, the OP is generally the least qualified person for estimating their skill.

Comment: I don't get where your disagreement lies. You're saying that an answer can be *worse* because it goes to the trouble of explaining where the OP's confusion lies? If the OP was not confused about something, then they probably did not have a well-defined programming question. Your example, seeking advice, is a recipe for a bad question (either "too broad" or "opinion-based"), right?

Comment: @Frank - worse, no . . . unneccesarily detailed, yes.  I'll use one of my own questions as an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343844/create-a-string-of-variable-length-filled-with-a-repeated-character . . . I think Pointy answered that just right for my level of experience.  On the other hand, had I made it clear that I didn't "get" how JavaScript works, a more approriate response might have included a mention of how `join()` works with array data.  It wasn't necessary to answer my question, though, and would have been extraneous, given that I already understand `join()`.

Comment: I would disagree with @Deduplicator's #2. An answer shouldn't be required to target "all readers"... that would mean that I have to write an answer that explains the basics of Javascript even if the OP clearly is an advanced JS user. Sure, teaching at everybody's level would be ideal in a way, but very time-consuming, and it would be *less* efficient for the advanced OP. So when I answer, I don't explain the basics unless it's necessary, and if the OP helps me know when it's necessary, that's a good thing. #3 is not always true either.

Comment: Ah ok, good example. It's targeted at the right level and I see no harm to future visitors in Pointy's not explaining from first principles. However, I guess this isn't what you mean by an expert-level answer containing "just the solution", since Pointy provides an excellent explanation. Personally, I think answers that consist of "Try" plus a chunk of code do too little for both the OP and future visitors, no matter their levels of expertise.

Comment: @Frank - Yeah, perhaps my "expert" needed a little more defining (or maybe a third "intermediate" level   :)   ).  But, again, like you said, his explanation was excellent, but appropriate to my level of knowledge.  That being said, someone new to JavaScript might have to do a follow-up search to find out more about `join()` and how it works, and I think that is also fine . . . it the fact that it doesn't answer all of that person's questions, doesn't make it a worse answer.

Comment: @Frank - and, yes, I totally agree with you about the "just the solution" answers . . . this site is about helping/teaching/learning, not fixing . . . that will never be as effective without some kind of context for the answer.  My original point was more about finding the right context for the OP.

Comment: Okay, fair enough :)

Comment: +1 It also means that when I write my answer, I know I won't offend or embarrass the user by explaining something at a beginner level -- in fact, they'll probably appreciate any extra information I take the time to type. Otherwise, I might feel the need to and a phrase such as "I can't tell your level of expertise from your question, so perhaps you aren't aware that the computer has to be plugged in" ... just in case the OP is Linus Torvalds. ;^)

Comment: I agree with this as one of those future visitors (see what I did there). It immediately identifies to me whether or not the following answers will be at the level I need them. This place isn't encyclopedic, nor should it be. I see nothing wrong with answers aimed at different experience levels, because future readers will also have different experience levels. How would you, as a reader, know that without some identifier in the text?

Answer (score 17):

Yes. "I am new to x", "hi", "thanks", "greetings" types of phrases should be removed.

I suggest to please edit as much as you can to improve the post. Only editing one word and or sentence (such as removing only "I am new to x") does not improve the post that much, and in that case you can leave as it is.  I often reject those edits.

Comment: Do reject when removing only I am new to X when that is the only thing to edit out of the question?

Comment: @NathanOliver I personally accept such suggested edits, but I know that many others reject them despite no longer having a "too minor" reject reason.

Answer (score 9):

I would argue that this isn't a simple yes or no decision. Every situation will differ. I would suggest you use a flowchart mentality. So, ask yourself a few questions:

1. Is the question close vote worthy due to quality?  => Close vote and move on.
2. Is the question worthy of an edit (implying it will either stay open or be closed as dupe)?

What I usually do  when I arrive at the #2 questions is figure out if they are poorly wording something that actually does add to the post. So, for instance:

> **Hey I am new to C# and programming in general**. I am reading C# In Depth. When Jon teaches new concepts, he often mentions the possibilities and limitations within the context of "unmanaged" code vs "managed" code. What exactly does that mean?

The bolded text does actually add to the post but, the wording is not accurate and is very much "fluff". I would suggest that in situations like that, you edit the post so that the information isn't lost, but the post can also be helpful and less fluff for others. So for this specific example, I might edit it to something like:

> I am reading [C# In Depth] by Jon Skeet. When Jon is covering new concepts, he often mentions the possibilities and limitations within the context of "unmanaged" code vs "managed" code. **Can you explain what this means from a beginners standpoint ie the simplest way possible?**

The title should reflect this information as well, IMO. To me, the *"I am new"* piece of information is actually useful information that will most likely affect the answers. So, mirror that reflection into a more accurate question.

Comment: Plus one for `I would argue that this isn't a simple yes or no decision`. That's a wise sentence!

Answer (score 1):

Like with almost everything in life I would say: it depends. In this case it depends on the quality of the question.

- If the question is good, meaning it is easy to get the problem out of it and it fits all the other quality standards (not off-topic etc...) and it just contains a short statement like `I'm new ...` or `Thank you`, then just leave it as it is. Especially if you don't have enough permissions to edit without confirmation this would produce unnecessary noise for other users which would have to confirm or reject the edit.
- If you understand the basic problem and you think it is an interesting problem but the question contains a lot of boilerplate text like `bla bla .... bla bla...` - feel free to edit the question completely and nail it down like if you would have asked the question. (I assume that you know what you are doing!)
- If the question is low quality and probably fits multiple close reasons, why editing the question at all? Again, if you are not allowed to edit without confirmation you would create additional workload for other users. In this case I would close- and probably even down-vote.

Answer (score 0):

No. Knowing that a user is new to a language/technology can sometimes help explain why they're not using a standard technique, and will make the answer more relevant.

Comment: Your reasoning is backwards: Even if the asker might be pardoned for ignorance of the proper way to do things due to general inexperience, the proper thing to do is show them (and all the potential *other* readers) to the light. Using an awkward and dangerous way to do something needs a good rationale, and you have to weigh whether the provided rationale is *good enough*.

Comment: I'm saying that if a newbie is doing something weird, the right answer might be to just put them on the right path. If an experienced user is doing something weird, you can assume they know what the standard technique is and aren't using it for some reason, so you can focus on the problem at hand.

Comment: Actually, even experienced users sometimes make really strange things without need. Also, they might just not be experienced enough in that specific corner. Anyway, if they are experienced in asking others for help, especially over the internet, and they do it weird on purpose, they will *know* to justify their decision.

Answer (score 0):

I think on some level, it's nice because it gives those answering the question a feel for how experienced the individual posting the question is (so they know how far they might have to break things down to get the point across). On the other hand, it DOES clutter the question and at times feels very unnecessary.

In conclusion.. eh maybe?

Comment: "it gives those answering the question a feel for how experienced the individual posting the question is": Actually, it's really bad for that. The question itself will reflect it far better, and will come over better without such detractions.

Comment: Yeah, I see your point there.

Answer (score -2):

I agree with @talemyn and disagree with @Servy.  Like it or not, every answer targets a certain skill level.  I've observed that @Servy's answers tend to target higher skill levels, sometimes at the cost of the OP understanding them.  That's fine; he can answer however he wants, and likely his answer will help future visitors of the appropriate skill level.

It seems the argument is that it's better for posterity to provide technically correct answers that future users will find helpful, at the expense of solving the OP's problem.  @MartijnPieters says, "Ask yourself: will a *future visitor* with the same technical problem *care* if the original question asker was new to the language?"

But what kind of future visitors are we talking about?    I would suggest that every future visitor hopes to find an answer to his problem that addresses someone of roughly his skill level.  Without becoming a horrible, bloated thing, a single answer can't really address all skill levels.  The salient bits of use to an experienced programmer would get lost in a haystack of elementary material useful only to newbies.  Would an experienced developer consider that a "good" answer?  Probably not.  On the other hand, a newbie could really benefit from that elementary material but doesn't need the stuff that's over his head.  So to me, it makes sense to assess the asker's skill level and target answers accordingly.  That stands the best chance of solving the asker's problem *and* helping future visitors of the same skill level.

Often, much time and effort is wasted in comments assessing the OP's skill level in order to answer appropriately.  It really *does* help when the OP states up front that he's a newbie.  I think it's a shame to remove such useful information from a post.

Comment: Assessing the OP skill level in the comments in itself is contrary to what [so] is trying to achieve. *"Oh it's a beginner I'll dumb down my answer so I don't have to explain everything."*

Answer (score -3):

I feel like it can actually be relevent for the answerer to be accurate.

You simply don't give the same amount of details to a beginner or to someone skilled.

You may want to explain more steps to get to the same results to beginners, which is when such information can be good to know.

EDIT :

It seems like around half of us like to know the level of skill of the OP we try to help. So, to answer the question,  there is no general policy, it may be relevent for some and noise for others. That being said, why would you make the effort to remove something that some people like to have when answering a question ?

I think you should let it like that.

But it ask another question, should we implement a feature like  a scrolling menu where every OP can state his level and make rules for this.

Like :

-total beginner - should be used when starting the language/library etc..

-know the basics -  should be used when OP made some little thing with the language/library etc..

-advanced - etc..

-expert - etc..

-mastermind

Maybe that would a better solution than just removing or not thoses kind of statement.

Comment: Theposter should explain where he gets stuck. Thus, any answerer will have all the *relevant* information, without having to put up with and try to guess what such vague fluff like "I'm a beginning-to-mid-level code-monkey" actually means for the question. (Hint: It doesn't really mean anything.)

Comment: @Deduplicator - actually it does . . . it means that I can't use a ternary operator in my answer without explaining what it is, because they are generally pretty confusing to people who aren't familiar with them.  An unexperienced coder would need that extra clarity to learn from the answer . . . an experienced one would not.

Comment: @talemyn If which case explain it or provide a link or something for further reading, even a simple statement like - *"A basic knowledge of ternary operators is required for this solution"*. Half the time if an OP is asking a question that's above their skill level it soon comes out in the comments and they probably should have done some more research before coming to [so] half cocked.

Answer (score -4):

I teach many students. Telling people you are new to a language seems quite harmless, and may signal honesty. It may also reassure feature newbies who have arrived via Google SEO

Answer (score -6):

It is useful information to know the experience level of the person you're talking to, and it's also annoying to people who've spent half an hour formulating a question to have useful information edited out of it, because some rules bore has a different idea about what's useful.
Sure, SO wants to build a bank of knowledge, but why annoy questioners unnecessarily?  Questioners are not a nuisances who have to be corralled into the SO way of doing things, they are actually the lifeblood of the site.
There are enough improvements that can be made to questions that everyone agrees on.

Comment: So many things wrong... The level of experience needs not be written to be known. When editing this out of a question, you may annoy op if he's new, but you will assuredly un-annoy everyone else reading the question. Questions should definitely be corralled into the SO way, so that we can keep spam, vampires and lazy people's out. Blood of the site alright, but when the blood coming in is full of shit you need to clean it before getting it inside, or you'll get sick. And there's probably a whole lot of bad questions I'm not even aware of.

Comment: That is your opinion.  There is plenty of useless stuff that can be cleaned out, but I, as an answerer, find it useful to know if the person I'm answering is a complete beginner or not.  If SO gets too arrogant with new questioners, they will go elsewhere, and in my opinion, this proposal goes over the borderline from improving questions to arrogance.  Arrogance is the besetting sin of many knowledgeable engineers.