# Removing Phrases in Which OP States Their Skill Level

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

Very often I see people include a phrase like "I'm a complete novice at this programming language". Should this be considered noise and should I suggest an edit to remove the phrase when I see it?

I find the phrase unhelpful because the question itself usually gives an idea of the OP's competence in the technology.

What is a situation in which stating your skill level is relevant? Here is an example.

[Outlook Sorting Attachments by key phrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39793986/outlook-sorting-attachments-by-key-phrase)

I consider this different than [Should I remove 'fluff' when editing questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions). My question refers to a person including their skill level.

Comment: It’s fair game to edit out if you’re editing the question anyway, and if you’re 100% sure it’s not relevant information (like when the OP explains they’re knowledgeable in one technology but not the other)

Comment: _"My question refers to a person including their skill level."_ Which is fluff, though you may not have realized it was seen that way when you asked this question. That's why the duplicate was proposed, and does indeed fit.

Comment: OP stating their skill level seems like fluff to me, mostly because it's usually obvious. Also, even if it weren't obvious, it shouldn't affect the answer - a correct answer to a good question is going to be correct regardless of skill level. If anything, a question that would require different answers for different skill levels stinks of 'too broad' and 'opinion'.

Comment: [My answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296418/2055998) to a similar question.

Comment: I'm curious as to why the sentence "Also, what is a situation in which stating your skill level is relevant?" is formatted as code in this question. What language is the code in?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Yes, you should edit it out.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135619/295232) Sentences like that increase the noise-to-signal ratio and make a question harder to answer. Just be sure to improve other aspects of the post (grammar, tags, etc.) as well.

Comment: Or, to put it another way - it’s probably not worth starting an edit (that other people have to review or see coming up on their screens) just to edit out this type of thing.