# Why must jsfiddle.net links be accompanied by code while there are no restrictions for others like codepen.io?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

I noticed that when you post a link from jsfiddle.net without some code in your answer or question the system doesn't allow you, and a relevant message is displayed.

But when you include a link from other, relevant to jsfiddle.net sites (like codepen.io), there isn't a code accompaniment restriction.

Why is that?

I find it very easy to bypass the code restriction by just posting the code to codepen.io than jsfiddle.net.

Shouldn't all wide-used known code editors have tha same restriction as jsfiddle.net have?

Comment: These sites are all useful and they work for the questioner because there is no interest in preserving the question beyond the time when useful answers have been posted. SO must think different. The real question is if we can do better somehow, e.g. copy code automatically from jsfiddle to SO and display only upon request or other solutions, ...

Comment: @Trilarion "and display only upon request" won't work if the 3rd-party site goes down. People really need to post their code on Stack Overflow, and use other sites for demonstration only. A question can't rely on an off-site resource.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Yes, I meant copy code from jsfiddle to SO and store on SO, display maybe an attachment icon and display on request (in case the code is very long). This idea was specifically designed to reduce dependence on 3rd-party sites. You see that questioners easily bypass the current restriction because they don't care what happens in the long term. Automatically copying from jsfiddle to SO might be in SOs own interest.

Comment: I asked a question a little while ago about additional validation on posts that would potentially help with this kind of thing: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260039/could-some-bad-questions-be-avoided-with-additional-prompting

Comment: Perhaps a threshold is in order.  I'm sure the reason is that if jsfiddle were to shut down the impact would be high for SO.  If a sandbox site that only hosts code referenced in 2 questions on SO goes down, not as much impact.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

> Shouldn't all wide-used known code editors have tha same restriction as jsfiddle.net have?

Yes, but codepen.io is linked to on Stack Overflow [about 7,000 times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fcodepen.io*%22), compared to over [400,000 for JSFiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net*%22). The oversight is possibly just a matter of awareness. I'd never heard of codepen.io before you brought it up.

Comment: With [sql fiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fsqlfiddle.com*%22) in about 25k+ posts maybe it's time to consider adding it.  Especially, when there are reliability issues with it.

Comment: @bluefeet Yes, that's a sizable chunk of all SQL questions on the site.

Comment: @BilltheLizard You should consider also jsbin http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fjsbin.com%2F*%22

Comment: If adding sites is easy, Plunker sits at around 10k, https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fplnkr.co%2F

Comment: I wish people would stop using Plunker, its pretty terrible and doesn't work in some browsers (namely, the one I happen to use) :-(

Comment: @bluefeet: These sites are just making a parody out of themselves with these downtimes now.

Comment: Don't forget about jsbin.com.

Comment: @BoltClock SQL Fiddle is the work of one man, built in his spare time, funded out of his own pocket, the kindness of others and a very modest contribution from advertising. Your donation will be put to good use.

Comment: jsFiddle copycat sites are all the rage with the kids nowadays, @BilltheLizard. There's at least one for .NET (and maybe Java) too.

Comment: FWIW I'm seeing a lot of codepen.io links in recent questions.

Comment: @cimmanon I have a similar dislike for jsfiddle, which I think is absolutely horrible when dealing with angular (the tag I am currently active in). I guess YMMV. Either way, they're both out there and people will use them.

Comment: http://ideone.com/ would also be a nice addition

Comment: I do not understand this rule whatsoever. The CODE is on the Pen/Fiddle........ why make the user re-post their code? It doesn't include potential dependencies, etc.

Comment: @aherrick When the Pen/Fiddle site goes down (they do all the time) your question or answer will be worthless unless you've also included the code in your post. It's the same reason we don't want link-only answers of any kind. Always include the relevant information in your post.

Comment: FWIW, SQLFiddle may have 25k links but I very rarely see it used without posting the relevant query too (I'm struggling to recall a single time). In my experience it is generally just used to give us a dataset to work with.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea.  Links to working code examples or links to documentation seem like the exact type of thing users want.  Concise answers to questions.  All sites go down, even this one.  Forcing the community to cut and paste is basically enabling an army of "fair use" IP thieves.

Comment: @Jon.Stromer.Galley If people just want links to other sites, Google has plenty of them. That's not what this site is for.

Comment: Google is not context sensitive nor curated.  If someone asks if there is a good example of how to do "x", should the community create the example from scratch or lift it from some other site and present it as our own?  (I know you don't want that : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317145/is-an-answer-almost-literally-copied-from-another-site-allowed/317147#317147)  It seems reasonable to me that if offsite links provide a good answer that using them seems reasonable.  Why allow any links at all (including links to documentation) if Google has plenty of them already?

Comment: @Jon.Stromer.Galley You're only presenting two possibilities, and acting like those are the only two. A link to an outside resource should be used as a reference to support a full answer. A link by itself is not an answer. That's the way it's been for 8 years, and the way it will always be.

Answer (score 15):

It's not really meant to *punish you for using a code-hosting service*, just encourage you to not shoot yourself (and others) in the feet.

That said, [Bill's right](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262126/why-must-jsfiddle-net-links-be-accompanied-by-code-while-there-are-no-restrictio/262127#262127): we didn't require code for these because they weren't really on our radar as contributing to problematic questions. Let's see if they are now...

- [900+ questions linking to codepen.io](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=url%3a%22http%3a%2f%2fcodepen.io*%22%20hascode%3a0%20is%3aquestion), most of them [posted this year](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fcodepen.io*%22+hascode%3A0+is%3Aquestion+created%3A2014..). Fine, that requires code now.
- [1100+ questions linking to plnkr.co](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fplnkr.co*%22+hascode%3A0+is%3Aquestion), about half [from this year](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fplnkr.co*%22+hascode%3A0+is%3Aquestion+created%3A2014..). Ok, that requires code now too.

SQLFiddle and JSBin appear to be much less abused at this point, but may need to be added later.

Comment: Sites like codepen.io and JS Bin are especially annoying because they save changes over the same pen/bin URLs instead of saving in standalone revisions like jsfiddle.net does, meaning for example that a problem could just disappear completely simply because someone helpfully edited the pen that was linked in the question, to incorporate their solution. Case in point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143814/clear-floats-before-and-after-element#comment37256538_24143814

Comment: Just wanted to update this answer because recently I was editing a question and the restriction is there now. Sorry if this is an old question. ![Picture of codepen.io warning](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ApQiO.png)

Comment: Yeah, I added it when I wrote this answer, @aug - thanks!

Comment: I know SQL Fiddle hasn't been added yet, but perhaps if it is the message could advise that SQL Fiddle provides a _Markdown Output_ option via the _Run SQL_ button. The markdown provided has everything required  included, so it can simply be copied and pasted into posts to improve them.

Answer (score 1):

It's a misleading conclusion that there are no restrictions. The questions about your code on SO **require** relevant code fragment. It's just that there's a hardcoded check for jsfiddle, and not for the other sites. It's impossible to do universal check. The code could be on your block, on news group or anywhere...

It's just like you go on the walk and see the house with the board stating that throwing stones at the windows is forbidden. You go further, and you see the house without such a board. You think "Oh yeah, there are no restrictions forbidding to throw the stones at the windows here :D" Well, it doesn't work like that.

Only because nobody has grabbed your hand in the very moment you were doing something, it doesn't mean that that something was an acceptable behaviour :)