# Can jsbin and cssdesk links require present code as jsfiddle does?

Tags: discussion, jsfiddle

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26259306/1234256) is one of many that doesn't include code; it only includes a link to jsbin.

I've seen this issue many times in the past for -- besides jsfiddle -- jsbin and cssdesk. Can links to jsbin and cssdesk also require code to be present as jsfiddle links do?

Comment: Related:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262126/why-must-jsfiddle-net-links-be-accompanied-by-code-while-there-are-no-restrictio/

Comment: I was also tempted to close-vote as a dupe, but then again how would we then be able to report new sites that gained enough popularity to be included in the "requires-code-filter"?

Comment: Perhaps we need a question "What sites should be added to the requires-code-filter?", so suggestions like jsbin and cssdesk can be added as answers or in comments? Or is that question already here?