# Can an automated requirement to post code apply to all popular online code editors (jsperf, jsbin, etc.) and not just jsfiddle?

Tags: feature-request, quality-filter

These sites are likely to close down eventually or periodically crash (jsperf is crashed right now for example), and it would be very useful to ensure that as long as Stack Overflow is online, its content should be fully readable.

It appears that including a link to more sites than just jsfiddle requires code, but it's not clear how users can flag or otherwise indicate sites that should automatically require code. Is there a procedure for adding additional code editor sites to the list of sites with the automated code check?

Comment: It appears that code is currently required for codepen.io. My mistake.

Comment: MSE origin request for this feature: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code

Comment: AFAICT http://benchmarkjs.com doesn't host user uploaded content...

Comment: My apologies for including benchmarkjs.com in the original title.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Currently-restricted domains (note that for the purpose of this check, the domain has to match *exactly* and the URL must have a path - In other words, http://www.plnkr.co/something and http://jsfiddle.net are fine):

- jsfiddle.net
- ideone.com
- [www.jsfiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net)
- [www.ideone.com](http://www.ideone.com)
- plnkr.co
- codepen.io
- [www.codepen.io](http://www.codepen.io)

To these, I've now added JSBin:

- jsbin.com
- [www.jsbin.com](http://www.jsbin.com)
- output.jsbin.com

###See: [Why must jsfiddle.net links be accompanied by code while there are no restrictions for others like codepen.io?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262126/why-must-jsfiddle-net-links-be-accompanied-by-code-while-there-are-no-restrictio)

Comment: Is there a procedure for suggesting additional restricted domains?

Comment: What do you think is missing? Procedure would be to demonstrate a problem (widespread use of the site in lieu of code).

Comment: jsbin is missing. In the linked answer you added codepen with 900 questions, [jsbin has 2100 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fjsbin.com*%22+hascode%3A0+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: What about [github's gists](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fgist.github*%22+hascode%3A0+is%3Aquestion)? (and a few more using http instead of https) [edit: ugh I can never get link markdown right]

Comment: [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/) is an online editor and compiler that gets linked in the C++ tag often.

Comment: There's also http://www.bootply.com for Bootstrap which I see used often.

Comment: But the problem isn't attributable to specific sites -- rather it's a problem of referencing code on these *kinds* of sites rather than including code in a question or answer.  So waiting until a problem develops with a specific site is too late -- rather code should be required (possibly with an opt-out option) whenever linking to sites that allow one to host (and likely run/test/compile) code snippets. Thus the above list should not be a punitive list of sites that have caused problems -- rather it should be an inclusive list of sites that could create problems.

Comment: gists are used for a *lot* of different things, @Dave. We could add them, but I expect there might be some pitfalls; you should raise that as a separate discussion.

Comment: The check was intended to slow the growth of an extremely common problem, @Mike; it's trivial to work around, and folks determined to not post code do work around it. Trying to nail down every site on the 'Net that could possibly host code is not likely to be possible - I'd strongly suggest focusing on the most problematic areas.