# Can jsperf.com be added to the list of sites where links require accompanying code?

Tags: feature-request, quality-filter

Yes, the site is linked to less often than jsfiddle and codepen, but it has been used a few thousand times, and it crashes often, leaving readers of posts that link to jsperf wondering what benchmark code is being demonstrated or compared.

See: [Can an automated requirement to post code apply to all popular online code editors (jsperf, jsbin, etc.) and not just jsfiddle?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339691/can-an-automated-requirement-to-post-code-apply-to-all-popular-online-code-edito)

Comment: jsperf.com has been used 189 times the past year, according to `select count(p.Id) from Posts p where p.CreationDate >= '2016-01-01' and p.Body like '%jsperf.com%'`. Doesn't account for post revisions and deleted posts, but it doesn't seem to be used all that often.

Comment: I imagine the low usage in 2016 is somewhat due to the fact that jsperf has been crashed so much over the past year.  I suspect that if it starts crashing less often, it will get used more.  It's also a specific-purpose code editing site, which will always get less use than general purpose sites like jsfiddle.

Comment: Right now I'm kind of under the impression you made up the number "a few thousand times" and it failed fact checking. I mean the request is fair but just try to be careful with claims like that.

Comment: "a few thousand times" based on this lookup: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jsperf.com -- granted, I did not try to eliminate cases in which jsperf.com is talked about rather than linked to.

Comment: Also note that it is used in some high-voted answers, such as http://stackoverflow.com/a/9693933/256305