# How to fix an answer with a link to plnkr.co?

Tags: support, images, editing-help, clean-up, code

[On Jul 3 '14, Shog9 forbid plnkr.co snippet links without code on Stack Overflow.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262409/1033581)

Regarding posts left without code but with plnkr.co links: for [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=url%3a%22http%3a%2f%2fplnkr.co*%22%20hascode%3a0%20is%3aq), I may vote to close as "*No [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself*". **But for [those 800+ answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=url%3a%22http%3a%2f%2fplnkr.co*%22%20hascode%3a0%20is%3aa)*, what steps to do?** Unfortunately, plnkr.co doesn't specify a content license, so copying the plunk into the answer (as a Stack Snippet or just code blocks) would probably be violating someone's copyright. You can't just take someone else's code and make it CC-by-SA.

<sub>* (ignoring a few answers with a link without a path, like a pure *http://plnkr.co* link)</sub>

<s>In particular, for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22291446/1033581), I'd like to [fix the image link from postimg.org to postimg.cc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310325/should-we-fix-postimg-org-links-to-postimg-cc), but the edit is rejected because of the presence of a link to plnkr.co.</s> (this specific answer was deleted)

Comment: I guess adding code-ticks or an empty code block are not going to do the trick?

Comment: @pnuts links to the root of the site are OK and won't be affected by the filter, [because blocked links must have a path](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339691/can-an-automated-requirement-to-post-code-apply-to-all-popular-online-code-edito/339692#339692)

Comment: Help the answerer creating a [mcve] and include it in the post? (...)

Comment: @user202729 If one works to make a new [mcve], then one should post it as a new answer of its own, no?

Comment: @Cœur - Not if it's just a copy of the existing answer, no.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder plnkr.co content isn't CC-by-SA, so copying it would be illegal.

Comment: @Cœur - Ewwww.... It's worse that, it doesn't seem to specify **any** content license. That's important information for the question above.

Comment: It's not necessarily true that content *must* have a CC-by-SA license in order for it be acceptable to quote it in an answer.  For instance, most documentation isn't CC licensed, but quoting is acceptable.  For *small snippets*, whose purpose is *clearly explanatory*, quoting should be allowable under fair use, and the license is therefore irrelevant. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254757/link-only-answers-to-sites-containing-code-which-cannot-be-put-under-the-cc-by-s

Comment: @Jules so we have to trust slugster's non official answer that we can fully quote anybody's code on the internet?

Answer (score 4):

#### IANAL.

Not only is Plunker not CC-by-SA, I can't find any license or copyright terms on the site at all. In the absense of them, I believe all rights would remain with the original author (other than a fairly clearly implied grant of reproduction rights to Plunker!).

Assuming that's true (which is potentially fraught), my take is this:

#### If the indication is the post author wrote the plunk...

...then go ahead and edit the answer to put the code in the answer, ideally as a Stack Snippet where possible, but code blocks where not. Leave the Plunker link in. Say clearly in the edit summary what you're doing and why. The post author will get a notification of the edit. If they don't want that code on SO, they can remove it, although in that case I would argue they should delete the answer entirely. (That might go in a carefully-wordsmithed edit summary.)

I'd say that any plunk referenced by an answer that doesn't clearly say it's someone else's plunk fits in this category.

#### If the post author clearly says the plunk is someone else's...

...e.g. *"I found [this plunk](http://example.com) that does it..."* or similar, I still say go ahead and edit it into the answer. As [slugster says here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254775/157247)¹, SE works on good faith. If the original author is happy for the code to be on Plunker, odds are high they're happy for it to be on SO, too, with SO's CC-by-SA terms. If they aren't, and they become aware of SO's use of their code, they can ask SE to remove it. SE will do so. I suspect the need for this would be **vanishingly small**. They did, after all, put the code on a site that appears to give no guarantees about how it will be used.

Obviously, if you see something — such as a comment in the code — that conflicts with the above (*"Only plunker can reproduce this!!"*), respect the comment.

#### If the plunk no longer exists

Then remove the link, and flag and vote as appropriate for the answer without the link.

---

¹ *(Not saying I agree with the overall analysis, and I certainly don't agree with the tone in the comments, but neither of us is a lawyer.)*

Comment: Obviously, if SE want to weigh in and say "no, don't do that"... :-)