# Why is this question title considered subjective?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, subjective-questions

"How do you remove an element from an array of protocols in Swift?"

That seems like a perfectly legit question and I'm curious why Stack Overflow thinks it sounds subjective:

> [image: Stack Overflow making a judgement call]

Comment: The title is not subjective no. What is the *rest* of the question like?

Comment: Why are you asking this question? The [question you asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24974766/how-do-you-remove-an-element-from-an-array-of-protocols-in-swift) has not received any close votes (or up- or downvotes either).

Comment: Because I'm curious? Is that not a valid reason?

Comment: Why do you think that *Stack Overflow thinks it sounds subjective*?

Comment: Now *that* is a subjective question. ;)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry I misunderstood what you were asking. When I typed the question title, a warning appeared saying that it appears as though it is a subjective question and is likely to be closed.

Comment: Right, that is indeed what I was asking. I haven't seen that kind of feedback before; I guess some heuristics have been applied and they got it wrong here. Machines are not that good at determining subjectivity, really.

Comment: Don't think a little binary processing machine a human. If it was a human making that call then yes, they made a mistake, but an algorithm that calculates stuff like this obviously can't read the question like a human can.

Comment: I've never seen that type of warning prompt before and wonder if it's a partial implementation of my feature request: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260039/could-some-bad-questions-be-avoided-with-additional-prompting

Comment: Uh, it's a **computer program** that is trying to apply a few simple (and probably simplistic) rules to "encourage" people to write more effective questions.  Probably a hopeless cause, and certainly nothing to get your shorts in a knot about.

Comment: Trivia: My recent challenge [Caveman Duels (or: Me poke you with sharp stick)](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/34968/caveman-duels-or-me-poke-you-with-sharp-stick) also triggered a "question appears subjective" warning. Despite the system repeatedly warning me that my question is likely to be closed every time I edit it, somehow it still remains unclosed.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the "How do you" at the beginning of a title is the culprit. It's probably a major factor in the algorithm that determines subjectivity.

[image: How do you help grandma carry in the groceries?]

Changing the "How do you" part to "How to" makes the banner go away. I think the algorithm puts too much emphasis on the **you** in that phrase, as in it thinks you're trying to ask each individual person "How do *you* do this?" rather than a general "How is [this task] done?"

Comment: Ah haha so my coloquial grammar is at fault here. Good to know for future reference.

Comment: Changing it to "How does one..." also makes the warning go away. Seems Stack Overflow encourages formal language.

Comment: That sucks, since "How to" makes a sentence fragment out of a grammatically-correct question.

Comment: @JoshCaswell That's exactly what I was thinking...

Comment: Well, there's no need to reword it just to satisfy the heuristic, as it does not stop submitting. Now if there was the problem with problem in the title...

Comment: I think action like this would be frightful to non-native speakers. I wonder if there are any statistics to indicate whether usage from non-English speaking countries has risen/fallen/remained the same before and after such changes

Comment: I hate "How to" questions, and will change them to "How do you" if I'm editing the title for other reasons.

Comment: @Gabe why is that?

Comment: We don't need a bunch of questions with the title.. "How do you do X". Write a better title. Titles can be fragments.

Comment: I would say that both "How to" and "How do you" are extraneous. For example, the title above could be changed to "Helping grandma carry in the groceries". Isn't it implied that the OP is asking how or why or what since they are asking a question in the first place?

Comment: Extraneous grammatically, perhaps, but I would argue that it makes the question more search-engine friendly. I tend to search in natural language more often than not, and having a title match the most common phrasing of a question makes it easier to find. "How do you" implies that it is a specific question someone has faced (hopefully with an answer) as opposed to simply an informative article on arrays and protocols in Swift.

Comment: I'm unsure how explaining MVC to grandma is going to get her groceries delivered.

Comment: They’re both extraneous, but “how to” is actually wrong (when followed by a question mark, as it usually is).

Comment: The simple way to both make the "subjective" warning go away and preserve the grammar of the question is to replace the *you* with *I*.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the label "Question: " encourages a Jeopardy mindset.

We don't need to ask a grammatical question in the title. We just need to make the subject clear.

I think "Remove an element from an array of protocols in Swift" would have been a good title.