# What is wrong with this title?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, subjective-questions

I am just about to ask a question titled:

> What is the best way to define a method on a class except for its certain subclass?

Then, a message appeared, saying: "The question you are asking is subjective and is likely to be closed."

What is wrong with the question (or the title)?

Comment: The phrase, `"best way"`, is a red flag that the question is likely subjective.

Comment: According to this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266888/why-is-this-question-title-considered-subjective) "How do you" is just as bad.

Comment: Then, what is the recommended way?

Comment: @remyabel: That question does not say that at all. What the diamond there said was that the *software* can and will miswarn "you" questions as subjective. This is a false positive, and "how do you" questions can and should be asked with impunity. There is no legitimate problem with them, and experienced humans should not object to that sort of title. "Best way" questions, OTOH, are usually subjective, and this intuition is generally correct both for the automated filter and for human reviewers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are asking "What is the best...". The best way to do something is likely to be opinionated. Therefore, the Stack Overflow filter tries to warn you about how the question may not have a verifiable answer. The exact relevant buzzwords were actually [mentioned in an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81236/261238). So, if you really were to want to ask that question in that manner, you could just replace that word with another that means the same (such as *preferred*). You could also just ask *how to* do it instead of what the most qualified is.

Either way, as long as you are able to show sufficient attempts and set an objective criterion for which the *best* answer qualifies, it should be fine. You could also change the question title to ask for the *fastest* or *shortest* way, which may provide a more useful and less subjective title.

Comment: According to a comment on the question, "How do you" also seems bad.

Comment: Right, but again, there are ways around it: how does one, how to, how would someone, what is a way to, etc. (none of which I have tried, but not all possibilities could possibly be blocked without major false positives).

Comment: "fastest" or "shortest" way is likely to draw out pitchforks who ask "Fastest relative to what?" I don't think it's any less subjective. Anyway, "How to" will avoid the warning message.

Comment: @remyabel I meant fastest in terms of execution time, but that is why the question body is also extremely important.

Comment: @Anonymous Yes, my comment still stands. There is no objective answer to "what is the fastest X" questions except for "measure, measure, measure".