# Why are well formed questions often given an automated warning that they may be subjective?

Tags: support, asking-questions

When I ask questions on stack overflow I try to make the title an actual question. Usually starting with on of the 5 w's who, what, when, where, why. I also try to make the questions reasonably specific to my situation.

Often I get a warning after typing my title that the question may be closed as subjective. It seems to me this is encouraging poor English and unclear question in titles.

My opinion is that a good title should always be phrased as a question but the bots seem to discourage this.

My most recent example is a question/answer I posted myself a few minutes ago: [Why does chrome display the pop-up warning: "Changes you made may not have been saved." on every page exit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39898072/why-does-chrome-display-the-pop-up-warning-changes-you-made-may-not-have-been/39898073#39898073)

It has happened to me on several other questions I have posted that were also clearly not subjective.

What about this question is "Subjective"?
How can I better phrase this and still make it a question following English grammer?
Or should I not be making it a question?
What is the actual criteria the bot uses to determine if something is subjective (so I can ask better questions in the future).

Oddly enough the title of this post was not called subjective. Thought it contains all the same elements. I assume that is because meta discussions are pretty much all subjective anyway.

Comment: I'm not talking about users flagging the post. I'm talking about the automated detection. Create a new question fill out the title and then when you select the description sometimes a pop-up states "this question appears to be subjective and may be closed by the community"

Comment: I edited the title to better reflect my question.

Comment: "Why" is probably the keyword that's triggering it. Most questions that ask "Why does this software platform do this?" are not able to be answered by anyone other than the person/people who programmed it. Maybe it'd be better to say "Chrome displays the warning "Change you made may not have been saved" when I foo the bar" or whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Why are you guys still upvoting the comment about the "flag"? The word flag does not occur in this post any longer. Look at the screenshot in this post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266888/why-is-this-question-title-considered-subjective?rq=1. Which I found after posting this answers my question.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I could rephrase my question that way but then it wouldn't be a proper English sentence. Should proper English really be discouraged?

Comment: *"..a good title should always be phrased as a question"* - I'd disagree with that. I'd prefer you just state the problem. You can ask the more detailed question in the actual question text.

Comment: The notion that „proper English is discouraged“ because an imperfect algorithm is showing a small hint is hyperbolic.

Comment: The text I wrote *is* a proper English sentence, I assure you.

Comment: I suppose saying proper English is discouraged could be an exaggeration. But I rarely see good grammer in posts and often see very, very poor grammer. Perhaps I'm not pointing to the correct cause but my logic is not unreasonable to consider.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan It's not a question though. As this is a question and answer forum it seems good questions should be encouraged.

Comment: Interesting that you are obsessing over whether the title is a proper English question, when you are spelling grammar incorrectly, but I digress. You could tack on "How can I fix this behavior?" to the title if you must. The key here, as it notes on [ask], is that you "*Write a title that summarizes the specific problem*", not that it be a question.

Comment: Somewhat related on MSE: [Should question titles be phrased as questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19999) Also: [Should question titles begin with "how to"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178454)

Comment: @JoshCaswell thank you that was helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That message is based on a heuristic.  It's obviously not perfect.  There are going to be some number of non-subjective questions that trigger it, and some subjective questions that don't.  It's merely something to tell the author to look into it further.

It's not like the questions are automatically closed based on the heuristic.  It still takes 5 users to actually close the question as being opinion based.

Comment: I dis not know it was heuristic. Thats impressive and good to know. Also kind of sad that a well written question is often a bad one.