# What algorithm determines whether "similar titles have frequently been downvoted and/or closed"?

Tags: support, asking-questions, quality-filter

I recently asked a question on StackOverflow and was warned:

> Questions with similar titles have frequently been downvoted and/or closed.

What, exactly, is the algorithm / set of heuristics that is used to give this warning? It sounded serious enough to make me second-guess whether I should ask the question, but my own gut feeling was that the question was a good one, and so I wasn't sure how seriously to take the warning.

Although I don't think it's necessary to know this to answer this question, the title of my question was:

> In CSS, what is the "nearest/closest-positioned ancestor?"

---

It has been suggested that this question is a possible duplicate of the questions below. I think these are all (perhaps [subtly](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)) different questions, but they are related in that they are about the same part of SO (automated question-title-writing assistance), and thus it may be the case that there is information in the answers to one of them that is relevant to the others. One of the questions contains [an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348825/4115031) which can serve as a partial answer to this question, but I suspect that someone searching for the title of my question will not find it obvious that the answer to their question is to be found within the list of answers to this other question. In fact, that other question may not even come up in their search results.

- [Don't show closed, downvoted questions in the "Questions that may already have your answer" list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335166/dont-show-closed-downvoted-questions-in-the-questions-that-may-already-have-y)
- [Why are well formed questions often given an automated warning that they may be subjective?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335833/why-are-well-formed-questions-often-given-an-automated-warning-that-they-may-be)
- [Why does "How Do You" trigger a "likely closed" warning on SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343833/why-does-how-do-you-trigger-a-likely-closed-warning-on-so/343837#343837)

Comment: I bet it is a clever Regex. What was your title?

Comment: I haven't finished the question yet, but the title is `In CSS, what is the "nearest/closest-positioned ancestor"?`.

Comment: Wouldn't the answer to that title be: See the CSS specs over at w3.org?

Comment: This looks like a candidate duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335833/why-are-well-formed-questions-often-given-an-automated-warning-that-they-may-be or this one: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343833/why-does-how-do-you-trigger-a-likely-closed-warning-on-so/343837#343837

Comment: The algorithm used can be found in [animuson's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348825/6650102) to 'Don't show closed, downvoted questions in the “Questions that may already have your answer” list'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The decision of whether to show the warning or not is based on the questions listed in the *"Questions that may already have your answer"* section.

As mentioned in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348825/4115031), StackOverflow looks at the list of questions in the *"Questions that may already have your answer"* section and applies the following formula to determine whether to show the warning: `(number_downvoted + number_closed) / total > 0.25`.

As for how that list of questions is populated, it seems to be based on the number of words that show up in common between your title and the titles of those other questions. In my case, the quality of the related questions (and thus whether or not the warning appeared) seemed to depend on whether the word "CSS" appeared in my title. I saw the warning when the title was *In CSS, what is the "nearest/closest-positioned ancestor"?*, but I did not see the warning when the title was *What is the "nearest/closest-positioned ancestor"?*.

Comment: So the algorithm is really just concluding that lots of CSS questions tend to be downvoted and/or closed. Not terribly surprising. :-)

Comment: This is also why we show a warning when a title contains "regex" - not all questions about or related to regex are bad, but questions where the title *contains* "regex" tend to be on the... not so great... side of things. This newer warning makes that automatic for a great many more such patterns.