# What is wrong with the Oracle tag?

Tags: bug, tags, asking-questions, tag-tips

I got the following error:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

The error message requires me to use the [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle) tag although I have used it already.

Comment: related: [Help the helpless with how-to-ask tag tips](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274632/839601)

Comment: Perhaps it would work if users tag it with [sql-server] AND [mysql]... [because folks love doing that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server+mysql)!

Comment: @Tanner Herr, dunkel war der Rede Sinn

Comment: @Tanner I note that the majority of those users have <100 rep... coincidence I think not.

Comment: _The error message requires me to use the `[oracle]` tag_  - and/or do a bunch of other things. You're singling out the tag for no good reason. Did
 your post contain any SQL?

Answer (score 23):

It is not so much an error message as a *helpful warning*. It is displayed *whenever you use the **[sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) tag***. It doesn't actually prevent you from submitting your question.

You are doing it right, you can ignore the message.

Quoting Shog9 from [Help the helpless with how-to-ask tag tips](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274632/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips/274634#274634):

> This'll pop up every time someone tries to ask a question with [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql). It's not context-sensitive - if they've already included everything in that list, they'll *still* get the popup. But, it doesn't stop them from submitting the question...

Take into account that this change is an experiment as well; Shog9 cobbled it together using existing tools and the shouty red background is likely to be swapped for something a little calmer if this feature is going to stay.

Comment: The red background is somewhat misleading though - people generally associate it with some sort of error. Perhaps it should be changed to something more commonly associated with a warning, like a shade of yellow?

Comment: @JonK: Shog9 hacked this together as an experiment; I don't think the tools he had available gave him the option. If the experiment is successful, I'm sure a better shade will be found.

Comment: @JonK maybe you want to show the support somewhere about [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274897/792066)

Comment: I would say from a UI perspective, while using a different color is probably also a good idea, the most important thing would be to actually *say*, preferably near the top, that if you already did that, you can ignore the message.

Comment: @neminem: I assume the eventual intent is to not show the popup (be "context-sensitive" as Shog put it).  Plus I don't want users seeing "you can ignore this message" and ignoring it without acting on it -- the fact that it's perceived as an error will actually be an advantage (once it's context-sensitive).

Comment: There is a golden shade used for warnings, if you look at Update 3 on [my post here], I guess that could be used.(http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260039/could-some-bad-questions-be-avoided-with-additional-prompting)

Comment: @Tanner: but has that shade ever been used for the *tags* box? :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Not that I'm aware of, but the styles are present so it wouldn't be difficult to reuse it I'm assuming?