# Can the tag tips be in a non-critical color?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-tips

When Shog [implemented this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274634/792066) for the [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) tag, there was [some confusion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274858/792066) for the people asking questions. Normally, this color of popup is related with critical messages that won't allow you to post a question:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

But this message's objective is just to warn users to make sure their questions will be well received by the community.

<kbd>[image: Very scary]</kbd>

Can this color be changed to, I don't know... yellow?

Comment: Or... white? Yellow doesn't seem good.

Comment: @JanDvorak AFAIK, there is other messages in yellow... mm...

Comment: I vote for blue, definitely blue.

Comment: I vote for yellow, definitely yellow.

Comment: [Why just one color?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EegG0.png)

Comment: @Mat: [Why, indeed.](http://www.dokimos.org/ajff/)

Comment: A client once asked for a yellow background with pink polka dots. I think we could make it work.

Comment: [Make the box bluer.  A little more...  A little more...  A little more...](http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2002-08-25/).

Comment: @RobertHarvey [Done!](https://gist.github.com/matsjoyce/006730bc4533a320a15a#file-tag-gif) Might be slightly the wrong theme, though.

Comment: MY EYES @matsjoyce, GIVE ME BACK MY EYES!

Comment: @Braiam A nice, flashy box that will discourage users from ever asking [tag:sql] questions again!

Comment: I vote for green, definitely green.

Comment: [I would propose a different color](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/209672#209672).

Comment: @matsjoyce: Wouldn't white be better for that than something flashy? I'm pretty sure the first time someone gets downvoted for not having read the white text on white background (ideally with a white border, so you don't even see that the popup exists unless it happens to be in front of something you were looking at) you'll never have to see them again. :P

Comment: Has to be mauve... http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/1995-11-17/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Validation warnings should be displayed as warnings (with the built-in style, which has already been in use for title and body warnings) as of build rev `2014.12.8.2084` (on sites).

Answer (score 84):

How about just using the existing `message-warning` class instead of `message-error`.

An example of what it look like in it's current usage:

[image]

Live inspect-able demo referencing Stack Overflow's `all.css`:

```html
<link href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="message message-warning message-dismissable" style="max-width: 270px; min-width: 270px; position: absolute; top: 26.5px; left: 10px; display: block;">
  <div class="message-inner message-tip message-tip-left-top">
    <div title="close this message (or hit Esc)" class="message-close">×</div>
    <div class="message-text" style="padding-right: 35px;">This is a meta demo</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Live inspect-able demo using `message-info` class for a blue dialog as an alternative:

```html
<link href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="message message-info message-dismissable" style="max-width: 270px; min-width: 270px; position: absolute; top: 26.5px; left: 10px; display: block;">
  <div class="message-inner message-tip message-tip-left-top">
    <div title="close this message (or hit Esc)" class="message-close">×</div>
    <div class="message-text" style="padding-right: 35px;">This is a meta demo</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds sensible.

Comment: There's also a `message-info` which could be used and is blue.

Comment: @Pokechu22 have added that to the answer too.

Comment: I'd vote for blue. The yellow one looks really... _blegh_ to me.

Comment: That's not yellow. Well, *maybe* it was yellow at some point in the distant past...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It's more a shade of what I like to refer to as golden turd!

Comment: @Tanner, that's very appropriate. Think we can polish it? ;)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Haven't you heard? About the turd?! About the turd, turd, turd! You can't polish a turd!

Comment: But it's *gold!* Gooooooooold!

Comment: [It's brown](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/209672#209672).

Comment: This mustard yellow doesn't really work contrast wise with the white text

Comment: Quick, everyone to the [bike shed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson's_law_of_triviality) ; )

Comment: Ugly inline styles....!

Comment: I didn't realize that people actually used Yellow Oxide as an actual color style as opposed to a darker yellow for mixing earthier greens.