# Give some color to [maven]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

#### TL;DR:

> Add the XML syntax highlight (just like the [xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml) tag) for the [maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven) tag.

---

[Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) is a tool that is widely used by Java developers to package and distribute their applications. The Stack Overflow corresponding tag is [maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven) and it has more than 39k questions with 5k followers.

A project built with this tool needs to add a file, [called the POM file](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html), which is actually an XML file. Maven also has a particular [settings file](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html) that is also an XML file. **This means that almost all Maven questions will include an XML file.**

As of today, and if I'm not mistaken, this tag does not have any syntax highlighting. What I propose is to add an XML syntax highlighting to questions tagged Maven. This feature would be great in my opinion because:

- It is a lot easier to read and go through an XML file when it is properly syntax-highlighted.
- I see no reason to tag a Maven question with [xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml) just to add syntax-highligthing because users following the XML tag won't be able to answer any questions. Furthermore, users posting Maven questions probably won't tag it [xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml).
- It is easy to implement.
- Right now, I have to edit practically all questions and add `<!-- language: lang-xml -->` to XML blocks, which is quite cumbersome (and I'm probably not the only one).
- Apparently, the same was done for the [ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ant) tag, as [its wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ant/info) mentions "Code Language (used for syntax highlighting): lang-xml".

Comment: When at it, why not also add it to jasper-report tag.... (the code included is mainly xml), I have seen you have edit some of my answers (to include language tag xml) thanks..

Comment: Nice, now I understand the usage of pom.xml, which always makes me look twice. I support this. :)

Comment: What if the question contains the XML file(s) *and* source code snippets?

Comment: @Holger If the question is tagged java (for example) the XML blocks will still be properly highlighted (I just tried to ask a question tagged java and xml and [it was properly highlighted by default](http://i.imgur.com/wVdGkzF.png)).

Comment: I've suggested edits for a couple of questions for them to include `<!-- language: lang-xml -->` before xml code blocks, for a **super** short term solution.

Comment: This is the first meta question that I've ever seen that has more than 100 up votes, *and not a single down vote.* Impressive Meta, impressive indeed... (In case someone ruins that... https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlYQ4.png)

Comment: @BhargavRao, I read that as p o r n .xml, and wondered what sort of code you were writing!

Comment: @Zizouz212 [*cough cough*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274897)

Comment: @SeanC I always seem to have that problem myself, regardless of the situation... :D

Comment: @Braiam [ahem](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vsYGi.png)  :)

Comment: @Zizouz212 Does an answer count? http://i.stack.imgur.com/O8Y66.png :D

Comment: I guess this must be extended to even [tag:maven-2] [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3298135/revisions).

Comment: @BhargavRao Ideally, maven-2 questions should be tagged maven also... but I guess it can't hurt :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've set the syntax highlighting to <s>lang-default</s> lang-xml, which seems to have done the trick.

You can now look at some [pom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pom) in all it's glory; [Maven issue when overriding an environment specific systemPath property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35510793/maven-issue-when-overriding-an-environment-specific-systempath-property)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Good to know that this is being taken into account :D. I found a question where it didn't work though: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35505966/1743880. It is tagged Maven but there is no highlight for the XML parts.

Comment: @Tunaki... Mmmm, good spot. I've changed it to lang-xml, which seems to have fixed that instance...

Comment: Yay with your edit it works :). I'll look around if I see any other issue but I guess that did it!

Comment: and for jasper report,when your at it...: )

Comment: @PetterFriberg: Done.

Comment: That was really a great message, thanks and welcome under the oak now that we have some more color.....