# Your tags cannot be submmited: [sql]

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, edits, tag-tips

I've used to get this same red error box when editing a question containing [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql):

[image]

And it was a bug (imo) because it wasn't checking that the question already has, say [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server), so the requirement to specify concrete DBMS engine make is already satisfied. Also why it's red if it's a warning, not an error?

**Now it got worse:** I can't submit an edit to this properly looking question:

[Counting the number of values for each row in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27279746/counting-the-number-of-values-for-each-row-in-sql)

[image]

Is [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) prohibited completely now? Or this is a bug.

Comment: Ah, I see what is going on; valid bug! (Just) related: [What is wrong with the Oracle tag?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274858)

Comment: The bug is that you can no longer *add* the `sql` tag to a post now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the inline tag editor isn't aware of warnings. That's a shame.

I've disabled this warning for now.

Comment: (Sorry, forgot to mention this was the inline tag editor) Thanks! It works now. No warning was shown and edit submitted just fine.

Comment: can be enabled again after this fix rolls out http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244607/your-tags-couldnt-be-submitted-please-see-the-error-above