# Is the "sql" tag banned?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-process

When I want to suggest new synonym for [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) I receive following error:

```
Failed to propose synonym
The tag sql is banned
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

What does it mean?
[sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) already has several synonyms. Why cannot I suggest another one?
I have not found anything about banning tags. How can I distinguish which tags are banned? There is nothing in [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) wiki about it.

**EDIT:**

Problem is solved. Synonym is proposed.
It is [select-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select-statement) tag. There are already [sql-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-select) and [sqlselect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlselect) which are synonyms of [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) and they are waiting for their brother [select-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select-statement) to join them.

Comment: The tag wiki still recommends using it, even.

Comment: Of course it is stil in use. The SQL tag is one of the most popular ones.

Comment: 'Is `sql` tag banned?' - I hope so, but I'm not holding my breath.

Comment: Looks like a conflict with the [new `sql` tag *warnings* Shog put in place](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274632/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips/274634#274634). Retagging this as a bug, this is [not the first such an issue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278362/your-tags-cannot-be-submmited-sql/278366#278366).

Comment: Just curious what synonym were you planning on suggesting?

Comment: The [tag:sql] tag is in the blacklist, but as a warning and is being picked up by the validation logic when adding the synonym. Kudos to @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll be able to suggest tag synonyms for tags with guidance warnings after sites build rev `2015.1.23.2218` rolls out.

Comment: Is there a public place where we can see about new releases and what is the current version? It would be nice to follow the deployment schedule and the changed items/bug fixes.

Comment: check in the page footer

Comment: Is that build number right? From what I can see the next build should start with 2015

Comment: typo fixed. it's the last number that's more important, the first part is the date...

Comment: Hello! This happened in [es.so] --> [bug report](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4154/83).