# Developer Story - Tags with usage warnings (i.e. SQL) break functionality

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

So while filling out the developer story, I ran into this issue:

[image]

I believe this is related to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284326/is-the-sql-tag-banned).

Mentioning SQL in your list of technologies is different from tagging a question SQL, because the question may entirely depend on the server, while I think it's fair to say someone is proficient in SQL, rather than specifying exactly which database.

At the very least, we should be told *why* it's not allowed. I would imagine many people will run into this issue, without knowing why.

It also causes a separate issue I was having before (but wasn't able to figure out why). In the 'Personal Tech Stack' box, clicking submit would pause for a moment, and then 'unbox' each tag (without saving the changes):

[image]

I gave up on trying to fill out my personal tech stack since it appeared to be completely broken and only just realised now it's caused by the sql tag. Also note that I am recommended to use the SQL tag, which further causes confusion.

Comment: FWIW, [sql] isn't banned it just has a warning attached to it. As you note, this isn't the first time some bit of logic has overlooked this distinction though... I don't believe there's any good reason to show warnings in this UI, so warning entries should just be ignored.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tags with warnings will pass validation in the next build (build rev `2016.3.31.3408`)