# The async-await explosion

Tags: discussion, tags

So, I've been pretty active on [async-await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/async-await) for about a year. Currently it's a C#/.Net tag exclusively as it's the mainstream language that introduced it.

Lately though, as other languages introduce this concept, new non-.Net questions have been popping around tagged [async-await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/async-await). I usually retag these as they don't fit the current tag, but that's not a sustainable solution.

This problem is only going to get worse as more languages add that (like [python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/), [javascript](https://github.com/lukehoban/ecmascript-asyncawait), etc.) and more people use it.

My suggestion to solve this issue going forward is to rename the existing tag and add C#/.Net (like [async-await.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/async-await.net)) and create a new all encompassing [async-await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/async-await) tag for the conceptual idea and not a specific implementation. (**EDIT:** I can go without the general tag, it's probably not that useful. What's important to me is the language specific tags)

So, what do you think?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79451/discussion-on-question-by-i3arnon-the-async-await-explosion).

Comment: The conclusion was to use separate technology specific tags. Further information [in my answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297440/885318) or in the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79451/discussion-on-question-by-i3arnon-the-async-await-explosion)

Comment: @i3arnon: I'm sorry, that's not the conclusion that reflects community voting here. It is a conclusion you may *want*, but it is not the consensus.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's not what *I want*, it's the best decision for the community that actually participates in that tag. And making a decision based on votes from users outside of it is not how you reach the best decision.

Comment: @i3arnon: those users have experience with the system and tagging in general. I do too, and there are going to be a lot more users with experience with the concept. You cannot close those users out.

Comment: @i3arnon: moreover, I see little point in creating per-language tags here. Regular expressions have per-language subtleties, string objects do too, etc.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the async-await tag isn't about a general concept. It's about the specific .Net technology named TAP. Regex is a language that exists outside of any programming language with specific libraries in each ecosystem. TAP has nothing in common with any other technology except for (potentially) using the same keywords. It would be like combining SQL and LINQ together because they both use `select` and `from`. I'm not keeping other users out, I'm suggesting giving them their own space. Why should I be able to close python questions just because I'm familiar with TAP?

Comment: Then create a TAP tag and start using it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If I create a TAP tag, and retag all the current questions in async-await, and copy over the tag info and tag synonyms, how would that be any different than simply renaming the current tag?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have no problem with doing that. Would I really be able to?

Comment: There is no rename option for tags, not really. If you were tagging TAP questions with `async-await` (which is a specific coroutines approach) then why did you use the tag in the first place?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I didn't tag anything. The async-await tag isn't about an approach, it's about the technology. The async await words just make a better name. And people used it to mean the same thing, TAP.

Comment: No, the [tag:async-await] tag appears to have been used almost exclusively for the Microsoft .NET TAP architecture, because that architecture uses async-await to implement it. The tag is very definitely about the concept. There are more platforms that have the concept now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If it's used **exclusively** for a specific technology, how can it be about a general programming concept?

Comment: It is only been used exclusively for that tech because you kept removing the tags from other languages!

Comment: @MartijnPieters no. It was used for that long before I started answering questions, and long before these languages added these features. It was always a .Net specific tag, and .Net wasn't the first to add the feature the name wouldn't be async-await.

Comment: So now that other languages have the concept and use those names, the tag is no longer just for the one language. We are going in circles here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It started as async-ctp (which is now a synonym) which was the name the .Net team gave the CTP.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's a problem with the name, not the tag. That's why I suggested changing the name. If that's impossible then we can hack it by creating a new tag, retagging all the questions and copying the info, and so clearing out the general async-await tag to everyone who wants to ask a general concept question

Comment: I fear that that's your choice. I don't think there is *any* point in creating a new tag here, really.

Comment: @MartijnPieters there's no point in shoving 4 different technologies into a single tag just because they happen to share the same keyword. Not a single person would be able to answer a question in the different technology without being proficient in it beforehand (unlike a regex question).

Comment: @i3arnon: Looking at the .NET pages on the subject the tech *is concept is not actually different*. And different languages have vast differences in regex implementations and edge cases, but you can still become an expert in them in different languages by learning about those differences. And again, community consensus has already been stated; the tag can be used for the different technologies just fine.

Comment: @i3arnon: and as Hans already pointed out, you just follow [tag:.net] + [tag:async-await], perhaps add [tag:python] and [tag:dart] and [tag:javascript] to your ignores and just get on what you already did before. Nothing much is changing here, you'll still get your .NET async-await questions served to you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters As I already stated... [this isn't possible](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234374/246036).

Comment: @i3arnon: I didn't know the filters feature doesn't use AND; that's then a broken feature as far as that is concerned. My RSS feeds do that just *fine* however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I think this retagging was not necessary. We (i3arnon, Robert and me) reached a consensus in chat that everyone was fine with - even if I (and the voters on Hans' answer) felt that it is not optimal, I had hoped we arrived at a conclusion and didn't need to bring this up again.

Comment: @Bergi: but it doesn't reflect the community consensus, *at all*. I don't agree, nor does Shog (CM), nor do the voters here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Have you talked with RobertHarvey about this? We knew that community consensus was different, but we didn't want to harm the .net [async-await] community whose workflow seemed to break. I had hoped to fix this (and align with consensus) when that RSS bug was fixed.

Comment: @Bergi: I have. I also talked with the CM team and other moderators. The community feels there is no point in per-language tags for the same concept across all those languages, other moderators and a CM agree. Most importantly, so does the community vote.

Comment: @bergi I did this for the ecmascript tag, because ecmascript-async-await is an actual committee proposal and only 19 or so questions needed retagging, but I don't consider it a generalized solution.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You (and the voters) still don't understand that it's not a concept. It's a technology. It's like saying there's no need in an EntityFramework tag or a Hibernate tag as we can simply use ORM and .Net tag (even though that filter isn't possible).

Answer (score -6, accepted):

After thorough deliberation I've managed to convince [Robert Harvey♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/102937/robert-harvey) that separate tags for different technologies will benefit everyone ([partly since you can't filter by tag combinations everywhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234374/246036))

We went ahead and created a new tag for questions regarding [async functions in javascript](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait) named [ecmascript-async-await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-async-await) and [async-await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/async-await) remains only for .Net's [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx).

As requested, a summary of my arguments:

- The [async-await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/async-await) tag, while colloquially named "async-await", is actually about TAP (Task-based Asynchronous Pattern). It's already a technology specific tag and doesn't contain any general "async-await" concept questions.
- A general "async-await" tag would not add value as there's no reason people familiar with TAP in .Net should be able to answer javascript "async-await" questions (unless they are separately familiar with this technology)
- You can't (still) filter by using tag combinations in some parts of the site ([Support AND combinations of tags on the meta filters and RSS feeds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234374/246036))
- If javascript, instead of `async` and `await`, used other keywords we wouldn't suggest combining the tags. Imagine `EntityFramework`, `Hibernate` and `Dapper` sharing the same tag just because they solve similar problems.

The complete discussion can be found in [this chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79451/discussion-on-question-by-i3arnon-the-async-await-explosion).

Comment: Can you summarize the arguments pro- and contra for this solution per your discussion? You're not suggesting `[.net-exception]` or `[.net-regex]` either, so why would you do this here? Even worse is segregating other languages by prepending the language name and leaving the general tag to point to a specific language as well. That's wonky and will only cause the entire debate again in some time when other async-await tags have become more popular.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel exception and regex aren't specific technologies, they are general programming concepts. Questions in the `async-await` tag are never questions about the concept of asynchronous programming. They are about the specific technology named TAP (colloquially referred to as `async-await`).

Comment: @JeroenVannevel For example, you can have a single `ORM` tag, but you it doesn't mean you shouldn't have `EntityFramework`, `Hibernate` and so forth just because they solve a similar problem.

Comment: I see where you're coming from, but in your analogy you would create `Entity-Framework`, `NHibernate` and have `ORM` point to `Dapper`. If you're going to make language specific tags, then it makes sense to do this for every language.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel We did, it's currently only relevant to JS and .Net. I agree that `async-await`'s name should probably be changed to `async-await.net` just as I suggested in the question. But I take what I can get. A general concept `async-await` tag would be pretty useless IMO.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I agreed to.  [tag:ecmascript-async-await] is a point solution only for the ecmascript-specific tags, and only involves 16 questions.  I didn't extend the concept to include all variations of the async-await concept.  [tag:async-await] is still the preferred tag of choice for the C# variant, and the lack of a feature for tag filters doesn't justify further bastardizing the tags.  Lobby for the correct feature, not a workaround.

Comment: These things get hammered out in a chat room by 3 people these days???

Comment: @RobertHarvey I removed the scala mention. Is this closer? `ecmascript` question go to the `ecmascript-async-await` and .Net ones to `async-await`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey This is the correct feature. And I lobby for both.

Comment: @HansPassant: This isn't a major change.  All of the ecmascript async await questions (there are only 16) were given their own tag, that's all.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - what's the point in having SO users vote on these proposals when they just do whatever the hell pleases them anyway?  This entire discussion is nonsense then, just delete it and lets stop pretending it matters.

Comment: @HansPassant What's the point in letting SO users outside of these communities who have no vested interest vote on these proposals?

Comment: They *do* have a vested interest, read my answer.  If you think this little about the SO community at large then just don't bother asking them.

Comment: @HansPassant I've read the answer and it's not relevant as 1.The [async-await] tag is nothing like [database] or [performance] as I've explained in my answer and in the chat. The people who actually contribute to that community (Yuval Itzchakov, Sriram Sakthivel & I) know that unlike the people who voted up your answer. 2.You can't hone the tag query as it doesn't work. 3. No one would ever be able to answer a different language's [async-await] question (unless fluent in both) as they are completely different technologies that *happen* to share a name, like TPL in .Net and TPL in python.

Comment: @HansPassant You get hung up on the name which is the least important aspect. We can change the name to whatever works: [async-await.net], [async-await-csharp], [TAP], etc. It's named [async-await] because it was the first, it doesn't make the tag a general programming concept like [exception] or [xml]. The tag is already specific and if the name doesn't convey that then we should change the name to fit the tag and not the other way around.

Comment: BTW, I've just discovered the [tag:dart-async] tag which was created organically by the [tag:dart] community and has a lot more questions than the [tag:ecmascript-async-await]

Comment: @Robert Did someone through all questions purged earlier? And you might get lots of flak for the [.net-async-await]->[async-await] synonym.

Comment: I've raised this with the CMs to see if a rename is possible. Keeping the tag `async-await` for .NET *only* is not going to scale, it'll only lead to more conflicts as other communities gain the same feature.

Comment: The voting here on meta clearly disagrees with this, and for good reason: imagine if we did this for *every* common programming term or pattern! We'd have [python-string] and [javascript-observer-pattern] and [asp.net-mvc-mvc] and...

Comment: @Shog9 The async-await tag isn't about a common programming term. It's about a specific technology named [TAP (Task-based Asynchronous Pattern)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx). When the tag started the name didn't matter as async-await was also exclusive to .Net but that being changed doesn't make the tag a general one. The people voting don't understand that, but the actual community participating in the tag does, you have the top 2 contributors for the tag explaining that in this post.

Comment: @Shog9 TAP isn't equivalent to observer pattern, it's equivalent to LINQ. And the fact that other languages are adding the same pattern (e.g. java) or that other technologies use the same keywords (e.g. SQL) doesn't make the LINQ tag a general one.

Comment: You're barking up the wrong tree, @i3arnon. Technically, JavaScript is the name of a language used in Netscape/Mozilla browsers, but the folks who wanted to retag all other questions to [ecmascript] realized the futility of that effort pretty quickly. If the folks asking questions think the pattern is called "async-await", then you can either dedicate yourself to a lot of awkward conversations or accept that the birthplace of a term doesn't retain perpetual rights to its use.

Comment: @Shog9 or we can simply rename the tag to something clear, like async-await.net and when people type async-await they would get the all the options to choose from. People wouldn't confuse async-await.net with dart-async and so no retagging is needed. I'm not trying to be more technical and I don't need the tag to be called TAP. It's just a really good tag right now and this decision will ruin it on the technicality of having similar keywords.

Answer (score 27):

There are many [tags] like this, some of the more popular ones are [exception], [regex], [xml], [database], [performance], etcetera.  Used in many different languages but never a problem, the questioner never forgets to include a main tag like [c#] to disambiguate the question.

You just need to hone your tag query a bit to select only C# questions that ask about [await-async].  Use the AND operator, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/async-await%20and%20c%23).

And don't overlook the value of actually seeing how it is used in different languages, also the core reason why SO isn't split up into multiple sites, you can learn a lot from seeing how it is applied elsewhere.  When this helps you to post good answers in, say, the [python] tag about the same subject then you're ahead big time.  Everybody wins.

Comment: Or use the [tag:.net]

Comment: I usually do that, but that would make us miss some of the questions, as people don't always tag properly :\

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - questions can always be retagged and you could do an occasional wider search to see if there were any you'd missed.

Comment: @ChrisF the cost of having to do that with every. single. question. is too high.

Comment: You're right, i'm simply looking for the simplest solution with less ambiguity. Not just from a search perspective, but from a tag perspective as well.

Comment: Regarding overlooking how it is used in different languages - I started reading the python PEP out of self interest because i find it intriguing how they implement it across multiple languages and i completely agree with that statment. But i don't think it has to do with tag filtering.

Comment: Just to emphasize... currently everything about the tag (info, links, etc.) is all .Net specific.

Comment: Using `and` isn't an option. Because people just tag [async await], you would miss it.

Comment: Also, most filtering options don't support it, like email notifications

Comment: I think a nice test would be to ask yourself whether you would bundle all the language specific question into a single tag if the keywords weren't the same. if async-await in Java will be called [AsynchronousGenerator-AsynchronousWaiter] would you still want to include it? My answer would be no.

Comment: I didn't think there's an `and` operator in the search? "and" as a word that is on the ignored-keywords-list, and you'd just use [`[async-await][c#]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/async-await+c%23) to search.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Then [those](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/async-await+-c%23+-f%23+-.net+-vb.net+-asp.net+-asp.net-mvc+-c%23-5.0) need to be fixed.

Comment: Relevant: [Support AND combinations of tags on the meta filters and RSS feeds](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234374/246036)

Comment: *"the questioner never forgets to include a main tag"*... hmm... you should visit [regex] more often :-)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: I guess there is one problem with regex which cannot be corrected: Those asking generally don't have a clue that there might be more than one variant, what constitutes a borderline-acceptable question, or have any interest in doing a token amount of research themselves....

Comment: @Deduplicator I always wanted to have something similar to [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278362/your-tags-cannot-be-submmited-sql) for [regex]... I'll submit a feature request.

Answer (score -5):

I think a per-technology [async-await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/async-await) tag is due. I would run like hell from a global `async-await` tag, as I think the most use for it would be to newcomers who aren't familiar with the tag system. It would eventually turn into a garbage tag.

I'm not sure how much effort it takes to refactor `async-await` to something like [async-await.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/async-await.net), but I think it's worth the effort and I'm all in with  on that.

Comment: You can create a synonym the when they get merged swap them round so that [tag:async-await.net] is the master.

Comment: @ChrisF but async-await would still be an option while asking a question wouldn't it?

Comment: @i3arnon if the tag is synonymized, all uses of [async-await] would be shifted to [.net-async-await] or  whatever the main tag would be.

Comment: @Braiam That would be exactly what we don't want.

Comment: @Braiam indeed. But that doesn't answer the question. Will async-await still be an option? I think so, even for synonyms. That means people can tag their questions with that tag as if it's a general tag even though it may not be .net specific.

Comment: @i3arnon when someone tries to use [async-await] it would be renamed to [.net-async-await] in the case that the synonym is in place. So [async-await] would become [.net-async-await] upon submition, tl;dr: no, submitting a question with factual [async-await] will not be possible due the synonym.

Comment: @Braiam I think we're at risk for too many false-positives on that. I wouldn't want `async-await.net` to become a default "spam" tag.

Comment: @Braiam you just described how it is possible. It would lead to people posting general async-await question into the specific async-await.Net

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov that's not what I'm suggesting. Actually, I'm suggesting that [async-await] isn't used, not as synonym, not as an actual tag, for the same reasons you wouldn't want it as synonym of the .net variant: it would get misused.

Comment: @i3arnon again, I'm just explaining how synonyms work, not that I'm proposing that as solution, check my answer, it is very clear.

Comment: @Braiam you don't need to. We all know how it works. We're just raising the problems that can create.

Comment: @i3arnon of course I'm aware of the problems this would cause, which is why I'm against it.

Answer (score -6):

> My suggestion to solve this issue going forward is to rename the existing tag and add C#/.Net (like async-await.net)

If you find an actual usage, this is fine.

> and create a new all encompassing async-await tag for the conceptual idea and not a specific implementation.

And this is not fine.

You are basically saying that you don't want problems when the tag is used for what you are interested, but leave the problem to your fellow answerers of other languages to figure out?

You found how quickly that tag got misused for the C#/.NET guys, and now you are essentially shifting the problem to someone else. I say, if those languages believe that they need a tag for async-await method/function/whatever, they would create them organically.

Not all implementations are equal across the board, so you can't have a all encompasing, ambiguous tag for others to use that you wouldn't use yourself.

Comment: *If you find an actual usage, this is fine* Doesn't the question seem like there already exists an "actual usage"?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I'm contrasting both parts of the solution presented. If someone finds that they need a tag to categorize a determinated topic, that is fine. But leaving a loose end on the other hand for others to clean up is not.

Comment: @Braiam that really wasn't what I meant. I see the general tag as a general one for everybody. I can see people tag questions as both async-await AND async-await.Net. There are already many examples for that. When I ask a mongodb question i tag it mongodb AND mongodb-csharp-driver.

Comment: But I do agree a general tag is probably not that useful.

Comment: @i3arnon the problem with "general tags" is that there isn't a clear boundary of when the tag shouldn't be used. I'm saying that if you are going to propose a solution, make it complete. Ask for retagging [async-await] + [c#]/[.net] to something else, and remove [async-await] from everything else. I'm not saying that we don't have a problem, I'm saying lets fix it completly and in a way that doesn't creates troubles for someone else.

Comment: @Braiam I'm cool with that (I actually just added it to the question). The point I was trying to make was about the language specific tags. I don't care about the general one.

Comment: @i3arnon oh, [maybe we were so focused on our own problems...](http://xkcd.com/1028/)