# An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure

Tags: discussion, feature-request, low-quality-posts

I recently commented on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29029897/1075247) question, and it occurred to me that there were some red flags that should have stopped it form being able to be posted.

1. All caps title
2. 'HEL.P' was clearly used to get around  the 'HELP' restrictions.
3. All code question
4. There's already a deluge of question in the form of ' code is not working', and they all appear when you type that in as the title - it looks like everyone else is posting them and it's ok.

Do these items not stop the user from posting ? I feel like they should.

Do they not enter a VLQ queue before appearing on the site? I'd imagine that would be more helpful that it getting 10+ downvotes (deservedly so, in some sense) but whereas that sort of reaction should be for when someone established tries to get away from something terrible, it shouldn't be used on someone who probably doesn't understand the question.

Could we:

a) Get the above points I mentioned in to the system to block posting before they're fixed?
 b) Especially hiding suggested questions that might support them thinking 'this is a good thing to post'
 c) Notifying the user when they get below a certain vote count (-3?)
 d) Hiding the vote that from them to stop them form being put off.

Perhaps we need to only do this for users under a certain rep score.

I'm really certain how we should handle this properly. Clearly we want the user back, to ask good questions and improve their question. Nipping it in the bud now would help create better programmers and better question-askers both of which benefit the system.

Can we do something about this, to help?

Comment: That specific question was closed about 2 minutes after it was posted. I don't see a problem here... SO is perfectly capable of handling such poor questions. Adding extra conditions like you suggest only increases the chance that a valid post is blocked, for whatever reason.

Comment: @Cerbrus my problem is that a) it was posted (validating the user that posting it was ok) and b) it got DVTH (validating to the user that this place *is not nice*). I'm not worried about those question being closed or not, I'm talking about avoiding having to. "An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure"

Comment: DVTH? I'm not familiar with hat term.

Comment: @Cerbrus Downvote to hell

Comment: Seeing as the user appears to have consciously circumvented the block on the word _"Help"_  in question titles, what makes you think any other measures would help users like that? (Also, I suggest keeping the title as it was, as the current title is pretty vague)

Comment: @Cerbrus if we could detect that they've typed 'HEL.P' that should block from asking. Then the system can advise them on how to ask before they can post.

Comment: loosely related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260039/could-some-bad-questions-be-avoided-with-additional-prompting

Comment: @Pureferret: What about `h-e.l'p`, `héIp`, `|-|ê|p`? You can't block every single possible way to circumvent a word ban, out there.

Comment: Related from Meta.P.SE: [How effective is the quality filter against this question with all-caps brief title and text?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6850/40980) (note there is a "don't shout" warning that comes up for questions and/or bodies).  I assume that this is enabled on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Cerbrus `title.stripPunctuation().replaceAccentedCharWithgASCII()` would likely get 90% of what people would try

Comment: Other ways to get around HELP restriction: HELPP, HELPPP, HELPPPPP... you get the idea.

Comment: As @Woodface demonstrated, still massively unreliable. If a user _wants_ to circumvent the block, you're swimming up-stream.

Comment: @Woodface then add `"^help\w+"` into the regex. I don't think 'It's too complicated to cut out more of these...' is going to cut it.

Comment: `hellp`, `he|p`...

Comment: Is it reasonable to try to enlist the 10k users to work on auditing the *existing* "code not working" titled questions ([search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22code+not+working%22+is%3Aquestion)) and either improve, close, or delete those titles to make it less... that such question's aren't as common as they appear to be.

Comment: @Pureferret "help documentation for code fails to generate with ..."

Comment: @MichaelT "Hi We know you're looking for help, but questions like that don't get a lot of attention. Try posting 'documentation for code fails to generate with ...' instead."