# Specialized question body

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, low-quality-posts

I think my question is a duplicate of this instead:

[Could some bad questions be avoided with additional prompting?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260039/could-some-bad-questions-be-avoided-with-additional-prompting)

I don't know if this has been suggested before on Meta or not, but as the terminology may differ from one person to another, I was unable to find a similar thing.

We have a huge number of [garbage stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions) in SOF, which will increase further in future. People come and post a **very low quality question**, some time later that question will **receive 10 [downvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)** or **[put on hold](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)**, and the cycle is repeated as another newbie comes. Although they should read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section, nobody really minds thing like that.

We have millions of comments like this:

> Please show some effort
>
> Please provide your code
>
> So what is your question?

## Offered solution

Almost every question in programming field, needs the following sections:

- Environment
- Short description
- Errors or Problem evidences
- Showing some effort
- Simple and clear question

That way, the newbie presented separated fields, understands the importance of showing some effort, or showing the error messages or other stuff.

I think that would be great if we have separated question body in some parts like above, to improve question quality and remove the potential for low quality questions.

Comment: Not every valid question might fit into that format.

Comment: Thats absolutely true, but this is just offered as an start point