# Lowercase epidemic

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There are user(s) with hundreds of answers and not single one of those answers follows capitalization rules. **All** the letters are lowercase and their authors stick to this style *like it's going out of style*. Manually editing all of them seems like an overkill. Commenting on such answers and giving suggestions yields no results in my experience. How to solve this and is there a background process that will take care of this issue?

Comment: I thought there was an automated check for that. Maybe it just catches lower case "i" as I just converted this question to lower case and was able to post it fine.

Comment: I Find it Less Disturbing than Excessive Capitalization in Question Titles. (even though this is supposed to be correct according to certain American style guides)

Comment: It can be frustrating but it isn't capital offense.

Comment: I edited one of the those answers and commented politely. The OP replied he would apply capitalization in the future. Though his reply was mostly in lowercase :) I feel it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: I don't see the need for capital letters. All lowercase reads better to me.

Comment: There's even someone (can't remember who) who spends their entire profile blurb explaining how proud they are of deliberately avoiding capital letters. Completely. Entirely. Like, what?

Comment: At Least They Aren't Typing Like This. Some People Think It Looks Nice And Type With The First Letter Of Every Word Capitalized Even Outside Of Titles.

Comment: what are capital letters and punctuation i heard of these things but they are very rare in my country and i dont know how to put them in stack overflow can someone help

Comment: @10Replies Sometimes native German Speakers will capitalize every Noun because that is a Rule of German Spelling.

Comment: @RobertColumbia But, They Don't Capitalize Every Single Word. Capitalization of nouns isn't anywhere near as annoyingly ugly and unreadable as typing with every single word capitalized.

Comment: *"...and their authors stick to this style like it's going out of style."* Grammar Nazi here wishing I could edit the first occurrence of "style". Truth is I *hate* texting and refuse to participate on Facebook (or is it FaceBook?) and Twitter. Imagine how I feel about "ur" and "2b" ect. I'm really grateful on how little of this I see here. Peace!

Comment: @Glorfindel Yes, Title Case is Ridiculous.

Comment: Clearly these users are attempting to subvert grammar prescriptivism. They recognize that language itself is a construct that re-entrenches racism and sexism, but by dismantling language from the inside out, they are working to take the power back from the linguistic and grammatical gatekeepers bent on maintaining the violence of the status quo. Or…maybe they're just pathologically lazy.

Comment: Maybe they connect to SO with 9600 bit/s modem. Did you know that the less different characters you use in text, the higher the compression rate may be achieved?

Comment: @Glorfindel http://titlecapitalization.com :D

Comment: @CodeCaster personally I think AP Style looks professional. All lowercase is horrendous.

Comment: @CodyGray I vote the latter.

Comment: @Lanky: The site doesn't even understand verbal expressions. Duh..

Comment: @gudok <s>less</s> fewer ;)

Comment: @CodyGray poweR tO thE peoplE!

Comment: Natural next question: **JavaScript** or **Javascript**?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan `less` has `fewer` characters...

Comment: All lower case strikes again - now on Meta http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342700/multiline-code-block-in-comments#342700 (10K only, deleted already). No one edited it to have proper case so while it was up...

Answer (score 29):

There are many posts on Stack Overflow that have one problem or another. If the *only* issue in those posts is the capitalization but beyond that the post is understandable and clear I would find posts that need more edit work.

If you still insist I suggest you try the Peter Mortensen [approach](https://stackexchange.com/users/24885/peter-mortensen?tab=activity): steadily but with a strict workflow and extensive review comments improving posts.

As an alternative you can install the [Magic™Editor](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/blob/master/Magic%E2%84%A2Editor.user.js), proudly brought to you by some regulars of the [SOCVR](http://socvr.org/) room. It does fix the most common typos, including capitalization.

Leaving a constructive comment after you edited a post might be noticed, if not by the OP then by others. Don't forget to clean-up those after a while. Your comment can go like this:

> Hi! Thanks for this post. I hope you don't mind but I've fixed the capitalization and a couple of other issues in the post. I think I didn't change the intent but you might want to review my changes by clicking on the edited link. Feel free to ping me if I screwed up.

I don't think we need features to block/annoy users during posting that provide useful content otherwise. There are already some of those quality filters which kick-in on moments you least expect it. I don't fancy adding another [pr0blam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-one-of-the-worst-ideas-ever-implemented-on-so).

Comment: I felt this way six years ago. I'm kind of over it now. Patience level: tending towards zero. Proper capitalisation really isn't hard and I'm past caring about people who just can't be arsed. I get nothing from them, so why should they get anything from me? I've given enough.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit they can get votes... the kind that nobody wants ;)

Comment: That tool is the bomb!

Answer (score 11):

There was something a couple of years ago in one of the podcasts:

https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/07/podcast-60-are-we-that-predictable/

Around 30 minutes in, they discuss things in posts that would feed in to the low-quality algorithm, sentences starting with lowercase and lack of capitalisation was one of the things they mention: 30m 20s and 32m 10s. Whether or not this is enforced or still implemented, I'm not sure.

I remember this as I posted this question, which referenced the podcast:

[Could some bad questions be avoided with additional prompting?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260039/could-some-bad-questions-be-avoided-with-additional-prompting)

The idea behind this question was warning users with additional prompts where questions could be improved with simple up front checks. Obviously this is to do with questions, where as you're discussing answers.

Answer (score 5):

I certainly agree with you. It is like children not knowing where the shift key is, or just being too lazy to use it.

We need a **capital punishment**...

Sorry for the pun. Don't raise your case at me, I will lower it, and make you ill like a pandemic.

However, there needs to be some sort of actual system in which someone moderates the comments, or simply just a HTML check to see if all the characters are lowercase on a response.
It's down to laziness more than anything I believe, and we won't change that for a while unfortunately.