# Possible to suspend account and reactivate?

Tags: support, deleted-users

Related to : [We'll always endeavor to do what's right. We'll try to do It better next time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342903/well-always-endeavor-to-do-whats-right-well-try-to-do-it-better-next-time)

Given the position of StackOverflow that it has the right to push (and heavily encourage) a political stance, I would like to know if it is possible to suspend an account, so that all posts belong to a generic "user19234849", but be possible to reactivate an account at a point in the future if the politics of StackOverflow were to change?

I know that StackOverflow retains all questions, and I am ok with that however for the time being I do not want to be associated with StackOverflow (or indeed any StackExchange site).

**More clearly:
Can I deactivate my account, and reactivate it at a later point if I choose?**

Comment: Cant you change the name to user764357 and/or logout until later?

Comment: Just change your display name and don't log in.

Comment: It is possible to change a display name across that many sites?

Comment: Yes, you can apply profile changes to all sites.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As far as I know, no, what you are asking for is not possible. You basically have three options:

1. You can change your user name so it can no longer be associated with any of your other online identities. Nothing else will change, but you can do this by yourself and still retain full control over your content.
2. You can ask that a moderator or the team place a temporary *suspension* on your account so that you will no longer be able to participate on Stack Overflow. Your account will remain intact, and your activity will continue to be associated with your account, but your reputation will drop to 1 for the duration and you won't be able to do anything until the suspension expires. We've had people who claimed to be chronically addicted to Stack Overflow ask for their account to be suspended, and as far as I can remember, their request was obliged.
3. You can [contact the team](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) and ask that all of your contributions (or any individual contributions) be dissociated from your account. This is probably the closest to what you're asking for, since your name will no longer be associated with any of your posts—they'll just have an anonymized "userXXXXXX" name attached to them. The problem with this is that it is *permanent*. You can return to Stack Overflow any time you want, but you will not be able to regain ownership of your dissociated content.

Obviously, if you wish to take such a stand, it is entirely your right and you should feel free to do so.

However, if I may be allowed to editorialize a bit, I would urge you to reconsider. Joel Spolsky and other members of the Stack Overflow team may have an obvious political bias, and they may choose to share that message on their website. That is not the same as "enforcing a political orthodoxy". You are allowed to disagree, and it would be absurd if anyone took the opinions of the company to be a representation of the opinions of all its users.

I have a notebook made by a little company in Cupertino that occasionally takes political stances, but that doesn't imply that I agree with every action taken by Tim Cook and company. As another example, I recently bought shoes from a US company called [Greats](https://www.greats.com/). Their CEO recently sent out an overtly political message as an email to all of their customers, and [cross-posted it to their blog](https://www.greats.com/blogs/the-playbook/we-are-all-greats). Now, I happen to *strongly* agree with this message, but even in a world where I didn't, I wouldn't refuse to wear the shoes or send them back. Would you? How is this different? Companies have a distinct identity from their users/consumers.

Comment: Cody, do you still stand by this: *"You can ask that a moderator or the team ban your account so that you will no longer be able to participate on Stack Overflow."*?

Comment: @Nick I stand by most of this answer. The only thing I’m not so certain of anymore is the claim that one is allowed to disagree… But yeah, the portion you quoted, for sure. I’ll be happy to ban a user’s account upon request (assuming I’ve done my due diligence to verify the request was legitimate). But I don’t really see any merit to this approach. And I’d be *very* annoyed if someone tried to use this as evidence that moderators were censuring them, since I’m the last person who’s gonna do that.