# Why first person singular lowercase?

Tags: discussion

Recently I've noticed plenty of questions by people that use the English first person singular *lowercase*. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44507950/c-generic-type-in-uniwersal-repository). Something like "i tried to do this" instead of "I tried…", etc.
Clearly they don't have the Shift key broken, they use it in other parts of the question. But they seem to use the lowercase "i" *systematically*.

Since I'm not a native speaker (nor am I capable of writing a perfect speech in English), I'm asking if this is a common practice among (busy?) programmers, or is it just that people are too lazy to press the Shift Key.

By "common practice" I mean a *known convention*, used among programmers or just among SO users. For example, I've seen the word "*dupe*" used here as an abbreviation of "duplicate", but in any English dictionary you can find it also defined as a synonym of "fool".

(Maybe this is an off-topic question, but I don't know if I could find the answer in an English Grammar Q&A site, since this is a question limited to coding.)

Comment: Sometimes it's because they have a different primary language where that rule doesn't make sense.  Sometimes they just couldn't bother.  Not much to do about it in any case besides either fix it or ignore it.

Comment: I'm on tenterhooks watching the edits to this question, waiting for someone to accidentally correct the "i tried" example

Comment: The question you linked specifically ends with "sorry for my bad English :c", so this case (and many others) are probably due to English being the poster's second language. Regardless, we can't really tell you why any given user writes `i` instead of `I`, and I'm not sure what use we could possibly derive from this anyways.

Comment: @meagar _"we can't really tell you why"_... Well, my question is: _"is there an English language convention for this lowercase use or not"_? And this is a thing that _can_ be answered, and that is _not opinion based_. I'll integrate an example to the question to clarify this point

Comment: I definitely wouldn't say it's "common practice" but I have worked with a couple of first-language-english developers who do this, as well as the "u" in place of "you" thing.  I've never seen it done by someone higher than entry-level. Based on the guys I'm thinking of of it correlates well with the type of carelessness and unprofessionalism that leads to getting fired pretty quickly.

Comment: *For "common practice" I mean a known convention, used among programmers or just among SO users.* No, it's not happening because it's an accepted thing among programmers or specifically on Stack Overflow. Servy and Daniel's comments cover two common reasons why it happens but it's not considered correct here regardless in any case.

Comment: No, there's no convention. It's just a common misspelling.

Comment: @meagar can I ask you why do you think that this is an opinion-based question? "Is there a convention?" => "Yes" or "no". Period. What kind of "opinion" should be involved?

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus _"is there an English language convention "_ Yes, there is: English language.

Comment: A [similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342510/lowercase-epidemic?rq=1).

Comment: It's because they're illiterate slobs who can't take the time to apply what they learned in the first day of English class, and this is only the tip of the iceberg. Their sloppiness usually extends to the question itself and their overall thought processes. I just downvote these and move on. Anyway, instead of asking "why", which is indeed a matter of opinion, why didn't you ask "what should I do in such cases", which is somewhat more worthy of discussion.

Comment: eh, i'm just too lazy to press shift.

Comment: This is done to allow low-rep users to up their points by editing the bad grammar.

Comment: I don't see it as a real problem. It's like complaining that someone failed to use their blinker when noone was around to see it. Not capitalizing "i" doesn't make the content any harder to read... Where's the problem? I do correct it when i post an answer, or send an important email, etc, but for day to day back and forth in comments/chat/text/whatever, why bother? Now, things like replacing "you" with "u"... that's irritating.

Comment: Note that in the question you refer to, the "i" is also the first letter of a sentence, written in lowercase. Twice. So it's not just about the pronoun, but general sloppiness in the author's writing.

Comment: I don't disagree with the correctness of capitalizing "i". I just disagree with it being a problem worth worrying over. Yes, it's incorrect to not capitalize it, but... do we really need to discuss it or do anything about it other than submit an edit if you feel like doing so? Surely slightly incorrect grammar isn't grounds for closing an otherwise useful question... or to even cast downvotes...

Comment: I would expect this level of analysis in a research paper. This whole Q&A on the other hand is just amusing and strange. It doesn't get any simpler than what @Servy said: either they're non-native writers and don't understand that it's supposed to be capitalized, or they are and they just don't like writing properly.

Comment: This reminds me that I ran across someone somewhere else who didn't use punctuation (or capitalize letters of any kind for any reason). Annoyed the devil out of me. When I told him about it his response was, "i'm trying to learn to do better" No, you aren't. You're explicitly not even trying.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no English language convention to use a lowercase "i" in place of "I".

I suspect there are contraventions of English in that single sentence - and I'm a native speaker. I also suspect people who are busy and used to the quickfire nature of instant messaging just don't bother correcting their own text to "I".

Comment: Yes. This is often an artifact of circa-2000 teen texting culture. Some people haven't gotten the memo that it doesn't make you cool anymore.

Comment: @NathanArthur It isn't just the 2000 teens, the old school hacker types used to IRC do the same thing. I work with a few of these guys in their 40s who do the same. They can't be bothered to use apostrophes in contractions, or capitalize anything at all.

Comment: @Dan "i no its so annoy innit m8" :-P

Comment: So be honest @JonClements, how long did that *really* take for you to type before correcting yourself? ;)

Comment: @Makoto Oh - you know. Took me just 4 minutes keep trying to remember how to be l33t :-)

Comment: @NathanArthur I mean it could be a natural evolution of the language too. The capital `I` is really just redundant. Same with apostrophes, save for "wont", I'm not aware of normal words that are spelled "arent", "dont", "cant" etc. It's not proper, but it's not really necessary if you're used to it.

Comment: @TankorSmash Sure. But if your friend handed you something he claimed to be a reliable technical resource, you might question his sanity if it didn't even conform to generally-accepted standards of written communication.

Comment: @NathanArthur I've actually seen a few cases where people intentionally write lowercase `i` on philosophical grounds, rather than because of textspeak.

Comment: @TylerH I don't doubt it. That doesn't mean we should accept it here.

Comment: @NathanArthur Agreed of course, I was just adding another source for why people might do it, aside from textspeak.

Comment: @Ðаn No, they are usually along the lines of placing imagined importance upon the self and not considering *I* to be a proper noun, therefore only capitalizing it when it begins a sentence.

Comment: @Ðаn I don't prescribe to the philosophy, I'm only mentioning it because reasons were asked for.

Comment: @TylerH: And one case of someone intentionally omitting the first-person pronoun regardless of whether the grammar allows such an omission, for the simple reason that they don't subscribe to this ridiculous construct we call grammar ;)

Comment: @TankorSmash "cant" is a word referring to how a horse walks.

Answer (score 12):

> Is a common practice among (busy?) programmers?

No. Using "i" is simply wrong.

> Is it just that people are too lazy to press the Shift Key?

I think this accounts for some of the posts. When I come across posts like this, I hesitate before editing the post, because I sometimes wonder if it is worth helping the poster when the poster didn't even take the time to write a proper post.

Often though, it is quite obvious form the rest of the post that the poster just doesn't have a good handle of the English language. These posts usually have plenty of other grammar and spelling mistakes, "i" just being one thing that is wrong. When this is the case, I edit the entire post, and changing "i" to "I" gets included in the corrections.

Comment: Good luck getting the script to avoid auto-correcting `i` variable names, within code blocks or inline code, and also without.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I don't see why that shouldn't be possible. A script can just ignore everything inside certain HTML tags.

Comment: And also in cases where the code is not properly formatted to start with ("without")? Silently corrupting a poorly-formatted post so it becomes harder to fix is not a good outcome.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I have to agree with the auto correct idea not working well with code not formatted properly. I've removed that part of my post.

Answer (score 7):

By coincidence, I recently asked someone on the main site why they have written all 400+ of their answers in lower-case - my guess is that it is stylistic. Yes, it's annoying, and harms readability. [It's not a new phenomenon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293779/what-is-the-most-effective-way-of-encouraging-a-user-not-to-make-deliberate-writ) either.

So, for our edification, they replied (with lower case 'I's, of course):

> @halfer you don't have to be so authoritarian. As you can see here > [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), there are no specific rules about how to write an answer in terms of styling. It is only suggested you should make the answer as readable and understandable as possible. Although i agree with your observation and i will take it in consideration in my future answers, my personal opinion is that answers should firstly and most importantly provide a good,viable solution to the problem and be understandable for the op and future users. The all-lower-case problem not being a priority.

and also:

> Don't get so hyped up about some lower case letters

Does that shed some light? `:-)`

Comment: No, this sheds absolutely no light! You quoted a long text that was supposed to explain this specific problem, but it explains absolutely nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure what more information you would find useful, @anatolyg. The correct answer to "why do people do this" is, well, let's ask them `:-)`. I don't like this person's attitude - I think it is lazy and creates work for volunteers - but the reason for this phenomenon is not more complex than some people knowingly write in a sloppy fashion.

Comment: So you infer that that the reason is "I am lazy"? I couldn't understand it from the quoted text. I rather understood that the reason is either "I am stubborn" or "I have a very good reason but I am not gonna tell you".

Comment: @anatolyg: well, I see your point. Would you like me to invite them to this thread, so you can ask them? I infer from your tone that I have upset you, but I am not sure how. Apologies if I have. I would like to understand the phenomena too, especially if that were to aid us in discouraging it.

Comment: No personal feelings - this is just a discussion. A genuine search for truth, which will likely not succeed.

Answer (score 3):

The most simple explaination is, people don't know it better. This general applies to misspelling and grammar issues.

For example, `I` is in germany `ich`, not `Ich`. <s>I am sure there are more languages where this is spelled lower.</s> [English is the only Language where this word gets capitalized:](http://blog.dictionary.com/whycapitali/)

> Even though it feels natural to English speakers, capitalizing I is unusual. In fact, English is the only language that does.

Until someone explained it to me, I was guilty my self.

Comment: I cannot agree that people don't know better. Every English sentence they read in a book or newspaper has "I" capitalized correctly. Every English class teaches this early in the process.

Comment: @EricAya it wasn't meant to be rude. (my english skills are not the best) I wanted to say, at least in my case, I didn't know about writing it so, hence *impossible* did not make much sence to me. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

For some people, whose native language doesn't have this rule, it may seem pretentious to capitalize "I". Especially, when in their language it's the other way around - you don't capitalize the first person, but you usually capitalize the second person (as in Polish). Of course this is also because such people don't know that this is a language rule, not being pretentious. I was among these people many years ago :)

Comment: I'm not saying that "I" _is_ pretentious, I'm saying that it *may seem pretentious for people that don't know it's, in fact, not*.

Comment: *but you usually capitalize the second person* Interesting. I think this also explains some odd capitalization I occasionally see in questions.

Answer (score -8):

I have used the spelling "i" myself for a long time. I heard somewhere that it was acceptable now (i.e. the rules of English language have changed); it was easier to type, so I started using it.

I reverted to standard spelling when I saw that people edited my posts to fix this spelling.

This may not be everyone else's reason, but anyway the answers here lack first person experience, so I added mine.

Comment: Any source for the rules of English changing in this matter?

Comment: If I had the source, I'd link to it.

Comment: "I heard somewhere" is *never* a reputable source.

Comment: Where is this "somwhere" where you heard that "it was acceptable now"?

Comment: @BartoszKP There are no "rules of English". It is defined by its speakers and usage, and as such the English language is probably the most democratic system ever to exist. Right now, its speakers are overwhelmingly in agreement that it should be "I" and not "i" (although this could change in the future), but this is a matter of *convention*, rather than *rule*. Anyone who claims that any given spelling or usage is "flat-out wrong" is, well, wrong. As this is simply not how language works.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Indeed, the fact that there is no official body controlling the English language is something I didn't know - thanks!. However the problem of divergence between *official rules* and *usus* is a bit more complicated in languages than you say it is, and your statement that spelling or usage cannot be "flat-out wrong" in general, because you suggest it's not how languages work is flat-out wrong :) Some language have official regulators and the divergence between the rules and usus is clear.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker In case of English hover, you're just juggling with almost synonymous words. The fact that something is in *every* (I think generalization is safe here) grammar book and dictionary, even though they are private publications, makes this a commonly respected "convention" - which is not very different from a "rule".

Comment: It's good to be honest, no shame in that :) And the learning moment is: always question information.

Answer (score -13):

In 99% of applications be it word, or text "i" is auto corrected to "I" because there is zero ambiguity.  This leaves the average person to rely on autocorrect, and never save their pinky a little effort.

Comment: That's quite a generous percentage.  I get it for texting, but typing is another matter.

Comment: @MakotoI guess I mean it by words typed, not applications.  I can't tell you what I ever type that's not into Word, Outlook, Text, or code except to post on the internet

Comment: for (i = 0; ... Nope, Visual Studio doesn't auto-correct.

Comment: @RuudHelderman and how often do you type "I" meaning me in your code?

Comment: Facebook and IMS are responsible for an extremely significant amount of communication. Most forums I'm on don't correct i to I. We'll start with Stack Overflow and forums.getpaint.net. Go ahead and provide 198 examples to backup that 99%; I'll wait.

Comment: @Andrey `/* i stand corrected */`