# Should questions and answers in which the only problem is the first person singular lowercase be edited?

Tags: discussion, edits

Quite often, I've found questions and answers in which "I" (first-person singular) was written in lowercase "i".

It seems that ["There is no English language convention to use a lowercase i in place of I"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/350774/4528159) but my English isn't so good and I am rarely able to fix other grammatical problems, so I usually edit these posts only when there are also other kind of problems to fix.

Should I edit these posts also when there isn't anything else to improve?

Comment: Absolutely, we want post to be of the highest quality possible. That increases its value for future readers.

Comment: Just make sure you don^t push any to queues by accident

Comment: Don't do it if your <2k rep, your edit may be rejected as "no improvement whatsoever".

Comment: The questioner's rep is below 2k. Hence, please do not perform such minor edits as it will fill up the review queues and prevent others from reviewing  important edits.

Comment: Who cares the reputation of the editor, some one sees a post that needs editing, it should get edited. It doesn't matter. We have enough button smashing monkeys as they come to deal with it.

Comment: I for one cannot STAND reading questions with poor punctuation, spacing and lowercase "i". So you have my vote.

Comment: My rule of thumb: If I need to edit the question anyway I can also correct minor English usage mistakes. If not, I rather save my time.

Comment: Lowercase i is a sign of laziness and rarely a sign of non-English speaking user.  If it wasn't something someone was aware of the first time, they most certainly be aware of it once a diligent person such as yourself edits their post.

Comment: Be aware that this is a question which does not really have "Meta consensus" so to speak.  There is disagreement. However, it's probably *safest* in terms of not getting your edits rejected to continue on as you have.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I wouldn't usually edit a post if the only correction I can make is to change "i" to "I". It is an improvement to the post, but only a minor one.

There are two circumstances when I think such an edit is definitely a bad idea:

1. If the question is closed. If such a question is edited, and the closure is less than five days old, it is automatically placed on the reopen review queue, and so several reviewers have to look at the edit to see if it makes the question worthy of being reopened.
2. If the editor has < 2000 reputation. In this case, several people have to review the (minor) edit in order to approve it or not.

Comment: Yeah - the mods are already moaning about the reopen queue getting clogged with pointless, minor edits:(

Comment: @MartinJames Yes. I'm afraid I was guilty of approving a few minor edits to closed questions. It wasn't until I reached 3000 rep and could access the reopen review queue that I found out that editing a closed post put it on that queue.

Comment: @MartinJames where in Jebus is anyone moaning? I mean, the reopen queue is the only one that most of the year stays near 0.

Comment: @MartinJames, While the useless work in the reopen queue is a significant issue, the more important negative is that such edits of closed/on-hold questions deprive the OP of the one free edit-entry into the reopen queue. That free reopen-queue entry should be reserved for the use of the OP, when possible. The goal is to have good, open questions. In those relatively rare situations where an OP does edit their question into shape, it would be a shame for them to be deprived of the opportunity to have the question reviewed for reopening due to not being able to easily get into the reopen queue.

Comment: @Makyen good point.

Comment: In general, nobody should edit closed posts unless the edits are substantial enough to possible re-open it. Otherwise it is just "polishing crap" and a waste of everyone's time. Similarly, suggested edits on posts that are obvious candidates for closing should get rejected, in order to educate users to flag instead of polishing crap.

Comment: Note only the FIRST edit on a closed question will put it into the review, so Lundin and Makyen both raise excellent points: we shouldn't be making edits to closed questions unless we can definitely improve its chances of being reopened

Comment: @Tas I agree with you.

Comment: This seems like a misfeature. When question is closed, only edit by the original author should trigger the reopen request. Edits by others are unlikely to add missing information, making automatic reopen request pointless.

Comment: @Braiam: [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355341/1355315)

Comment: @MartinJames The mods? I thought it was only normal users complaining.

Comment: @Abhitalks and, as Shog numbers demonstrate, they have no reason for moaning.

Comment: @Braiam did you reread Shog's numbers after he fixed the query? It now pretty much shows that 3rd party edits on closed questions are completely useless.

Comment: @Ajean Did you read the amount of tasks created? Only 23% (588/2537). If there were a "overrun", one would expect over 50%. Out of 20, you would review only 5 due third party edits and that ignores those that are edited by 2kers, which isn't what the OP is claiming "edited by a user who is not the asker after the closure, and *their edit has been approved*"

Comment: @Braiam Eh, I think you are just reacting to the use of the word "overrun."  25% is not an overrun, it is true, *but* I personally don't think 25 percent is a trivial number of tasks that are pointless. (< 1% reopen rate).

Comment: @Ajean considering that even OP own edits doesn't fare much better...

Comment: 0.8% vs 6%? That's very very low but still significantly better, and the only thing that does work better is vote-instigated, and only just barely.

Comment: @user694733 my bad, posted the mod timeline access :( here's the post timeline https://devops.stackexchange.com/posts/764/timeline (point being my last edit could be a valid case for a reopen I think)

Comment: @Tensibai Ok, see it now. My point was that in most cases others don't have enough knowledge to determine what author wants to ask. For rare cases when it can happen, editor can do explicit reopen request. But, if it was question that can be salvaged by editing, then it shouldn't have been closed in the first place.

Comment: @user694733 Well, sometimes (few, but they exists) the author is not comfortable enough with the site to include the updates in a correct manner, and when the question is unclear at start, closing it prevent FGITW to try a 'guess answer'. As such having someone else editing the question and triggering the reopen votes sounds reasonable to me, even if it works in very few cases. I agree on the overall points there to not edit if it's a trivial change not bringing necessary details to the question, just pointing out disallowing edit by other doesn't sound a good idea for me ;)

Comment: @Blackwood: I've edited an important detail into your post, [source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325811/472495). Feel free to edit further, but I think that detail is important.

Comment: @halfer Thanks for the edit. I agree it is an important detail that I had overlooked.

Comment: No worries, I only just discovered this myself recently.

Answer (score 30):

It is rare that this is the **only** problem in a question or answer. Frequently, on looking more closely, there are other things that can be fixed. Any editor should fix all the faults to fully improve the text so that no further edits should ever be necessary.

If you are below 2,000 reputation your edits would have to be approved in the edit approval queue, so such minor edits should only be done by those with over 2k reputation. Just leave it to them.

You are correct in only editing these posts when there are other problems that can be fixed.

Comment: I'm not sure there's really a good solution for minor edits right now. The "workaround" is that <2k users have to post minor corrections in comments... [comments already have too much going on as it is.](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/97725/am-i-being-asked-to-lie-in-my-job#comment297808_97729) It seems inefficient to mix in grammar and spelling corrections into the usual comment thread subjects such as "There's an obscure bug that happens with this method", "For more information, check this out", "This doesn't work in Windows 10", "Possible duplicate of...", etc

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Blackwood](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355356/1207195)'s answer so this is just to complete it.

Be aware that OP may rollback your change back, in that case IMO you should simply desist. Most of times it's just a spelling mistake or a typo but there are **cultural/political/religious reasons** to use lowercase <kbd>i</kbd>. It's a complex opinionated topic, you can read one example [here](https://www.quora.com/In-the-US-what-meaning-is-attached-to-having-your-name-spelled-entirely-in-lowercase).

This exact problem has been faced before, here on SO, and usually (as far as I can remember) moderators used to honor OP's wishes over grammar rules.

Comment: "...here are cultural/political/religious reasons to use lowercase..." Interesting. Wasn't aware of that. Can you point me to some of these cultural, political or religious reasons to use lowercase?

Comment: Someone who does it (and explain why): https://www.quora.com/In-the-US-what-meaning-is-attached-to-having-your-name-spelled-entirely-in-lowercase. Note that both his name and "i" are lowercase.

Comment: Wouldn't be surprised if I was the one who left a comment to this end, although I wasn't a moderator at the time. bell hooks isn't the only one. [danah boyd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danah_boyd) does the same thing, for very similar reasons. That said, it isn't immediately clear why name orthography should map to question orthography. If you're protesting the Eurocentric nature of *langue*, you have a lot to be upset about here...

Comment: @CodyGray I can't comment on that, it's not only the fact that I don't agree -- with _break the rules_ thing -- but I don't event _understand_ those reasons...

Answer (score -16):

> Should questions and answers in which the only problem is the first person singular lowercase be edited?

Shog answered that already:

> can be blithely discarded in favor of a better edit[?]

If your answer is "no", then you should edit them, and reviewers should approve it. If the answer is yes you should offer a better edit. Also, skip if you are unsure.

Comment: OP is asking whether or not edits should be suggested in this particular case, not how to review them.

Comment: @Bryan that's a given. If reviewers are encouraged to accept them, obviously editors are encouraged to do them, don't you agree?

Comment: For users with >2k rep, yes, your point is reasonable, but not necessarily so for <2k rep users, which includes the OP.

Comment: @Bryan wait, are you saying that he shouldn't improve the post he can improve? Are you aware how absurd that sounds? Because he has less than 2k? Who cares how much reputation he has! He's improving a post.

Comment: I'm saying that advice to reviewers doesn't necessarily translate to users whose edits require those reviews. We're talking about edits that in the past many considered too minor. That reviewers are now encouraged to lean towards approving (and editing) them does not automatically mean that users who haven't yet achieved the "edit without review" privilege should be encouraged to submit them.

Comment: @Bryan there's no such thing as a "too minor" edit. Doesn't exist. Either the edit should be approved because it improves the post, or it doesn't.

Comment: @Braiam There _is_ such a thing as a "too minor" edit. The [editing privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) specifically states _"Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged"_. Whether or not the lowercase issue is a "Tiny, trivial edit" is debatable (IMO it definitely is too trivial unless you're >2k rep), but it does unequivocally prove your statement (_"there's no such thing as a "too minor" edit"_) wrong.

Comment: In my opinion the "no improvement whatsoever" reject reason is being stretched a bit far, it might be better to just create a new reject reason (clearly documented in the help center, i.e., don't add tags, don't just fix one thing, don't add backticks, etc. etc.). Then, if it's not already in the audits, start putting in audits testing reviewers on this reject reason, the number of people that fail "too minor" audits in both directions (i.e., accepting too minor and rejecting non-minor) might be a good indicator of how clear these guidelines are.

Comment: @Clonkex "discouraged" not "prohibited". If a post has a single letter wrong, for more tiny it was, it's **not trivial**, since I "[corrected] all problems that [I] observed."

Comment: @Braiam I'm afraid I don't know what _"for more tiny it was"_ is meant to mean. Ignoring that, however, correcting all the problems you observe_doesn't_ negate the triviality of the edit. An edit changing a lowercase "i" to an uppercase "I" is no less trivial just because that's the only problem with the post. It's still a tiny, trivial edit that doesn't _"make the post significantly better"_. Sure, it's not strictly prohibited, but if it's discouraged, there's a _reason_ that it's discouraged, which means the answer to the OP's question should be, "no, don't suggest trivial edits like that".