# How did this question even get past the minimum character amount safeguards?

Tags: discussion, questions, low-quality-posts

I was on Stack Overflow checking the questions until I stumbled on a particular question which left me puzzled, a 6 character question?

[image: Title: wath is sin cos in c++? Body: help r Tags: Java]

(Excuse the bad resolution and me being on mobile) - Why does the site allow this? Isn't there a limit to the [minimum amount](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/257910/5647260) of characters for each post?

If posts like these can be made, why don't we set restrictions in place to prevent this, as I don't know of a legitimate question at <10 characters, or maybe 15.

My question is, what are the current restrictions on minimum amount of characters? Can we increase them? Was this somehow a post that fell through the cracks?

---

The post had lots of whitespace, but shouldn't we be able to detect these things? If we implement something like that we could get rid of lots of low quality posts.

Comment: Please give your question a descriptive title. Don't use click bait techniques to attract users.

Comment: My oh my, I was gone just two days and now meta is advising against click-bait titles? Times sure are changing...

Comment: @Félix Gagnon-Grenier: If I see a title I want to have at least some idea, what is behind it. _note: Original title was of course different than the current one. See edits._

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: Meta loves amusing titles, but those are quite different from zero-information clickbait.

Comment: @BenVoigt What's amusing and what's not is individual to everyone. Not every humor is equal.

Comment: @bwoebi: That just makes it even more important that the title be informative.  Being funny is a bonus, being informative is a requirement.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

As you can see when you edit the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38259641/wath-is-sin-cos-in-c) (10k only), there's a lot of whitespace in it, but HTML collapses it into a single space. Some quick tests showed that whitespace *does count* against the character limit for *questions*, which is **30** at the moment.

> [image: Title: wath is sin cos in c++? Body: help]

Automatic measures to prevent these questions will *always* fail one or the other way. Luckily, for these situations, we do have the next best thing: an army of users who like to keep Stack Overflow a more-or-less tidy place.

<sub>P.S. please, don't use answers or comments to prove that it is somehow possible to circumvent the minimum character limits. These kind of posts, while funny, don't answer the question, and [a couple of them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pDiM.png) have already been deleted. For those of you who want to try things out, we have a [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) which you can use.</sub>

Comment: But then the question becomes, why don't we detect these things? We can all agree that question was quite bad, and it would be easily detectable

Comment: @AndrewL. Because they are easy to get around and you'd just end up in a whack-a-mole game. Easier just to downvote, close and delete the questions. It won't be long before a question ban kicks in if they keep that up.

Comment: @RobertLongson true, but shouldn't detecting things like giant chunks of whitespace in quick succession be implement as to stop these posts from happening in the first place? Just a thought

Comment: @AndrewL. You'd just get giant chunks of something else if you did that.

Comment: @RobertLongson Ahh, very true. I guess there's no way around it, only users to flag and delete these questions.

Comment: @AndrewL.: filler....

Comment: The life expectancy of these low quality questions is 15 minutes maximum

Comment: Why not hellban the question or the user? Instead of preventing them from posting a question full of spaces, make it appear live to only them and no one else--for everyone else it doesn't exist.

Comment: @ErikE Because in most cases it's better for misbehaving users to know we know they did something wrong.

Comment: I just hate having to type "......." to extend a comment or answer to the minimum length. Every time I do it, I think that whoever imposed that rule was a total moron.

Comment: "we do have the next best thing: an army of users who like to keep Stack Overflow a more-or-less tidy place."  - It's been quite obvious for a long time that doesn't scale, and despite all the effort put in, SO is *not* a more-or-less tidy place.

Comment: @acbabis: If the user doesn't know they're doing something wrong when actively circumventing a very clear requirement with a very clear message, I don't know that we can really so anything for them. Having tried more than once to deal with these people, I can tell you there's little hope for improvement.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Except that sometimes no one cares when people circumvent automated rules. That1Guy just did it and 7 people (including myself) thought it was funny. The asker of the "sin cos in C++" question may have thought his problem was urgent enough to warrant an exception.

As for cases where the user is clearly beyond hope, I think that MAC/IP ban is more humane than what ErikE is proposing. Most bad users aren't trolls, and most trolls aren't very good at circumventing permabans, so hellban or shadow ban is pointless.

Comment: `if( content.trimmed( ) < characterLimit ) return false;`

Comment: `don't use answers or comments to prove that it is somehow possible to circumvent the minimum character limits... we have a Formatting Sandbox which you can use.` <shameless self-promotion>To my knowledge [I'm the first one to do that in the Sandbox.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280790/329351)</shameless self-promotion>

Comment: @doru Unfortunately, not even close to being the first person. :-) But probably all the old attempts have been deleted, so you may be the most recent.