Was the minimum character limit for questions increased to 300 recently?
I was trying to edit this question into shape.
Due to removing some junk text the body became shorter and I got this error message when trying to save:

Body must be at least 300 characters; you entered 289.

This seems odd, I do not remember getting this error for similar edits I have made.
According to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327578, the minimum character limit was 30 (as of Jul 8, 2016). Is it now really 300 or is it a bug?

Yes, I also just ran into this. At first I thought it was because there was a link in the post, but I really am with you that it feels like a new restriction.

Went to remove noise from a post earlier and I couldn't because of this new "feature". The question was still low quality, but it didn't need to start with "Hello team, hope you are well" and end with "Thanks for your time!".

Good thing close votes still work on questions like that.

I wonder if the same is true across the network, and if it's true for answers as well...

Interesting, a significant portion of the highest scored do not meet that 300 character limit.

@F1Krazy tested it on an answer of mine and I could update it with 204 characters.

@ErikA Certainly just a consequence of them being basic and old, rather than particularly good in any inherent/qualitative sense.

300 might be a slightly high limit for self-answered QA pairs, where there usually isn't much left to say in the question when the most useful details have already been included in the answer. The average number of letters in an English word plus a space is about 6, which means a question now needs to be about 50 words long.

@InSync A self-answered question should still be a proper question that does not have to rely on answers for details. 300 might be generally a bit high for questions that are properly reduced to the minimum, though.

Seems likely that the site setting got overridden inadvertently - couldn't guess why but the minimum character count is a site setting. I have a difficult time believing it's intentional, so I'd likely guess it's a bug.

Looked into it - miscalculation. Fixed now, thanks for reporting.

... Why exactly is there a calculation involved?

Markdown/HTML rendering, at a guess, @KarlKnechtel .
